# Java 8 Streams FlatMap method example

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

I have been checking the upcoming `Java update`, namely: `Java 8 or JDK 8`. Yes, I am impatient, there's a lot of new stuff, but, there is something I don't understand, some simple code:

```
final Stream<Integer>stream = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
stream.flatMap();
```

the javadocs are

> `public <R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)`
>
> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element. Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream. (If a mapped stream is null an empty stream is used, instead.)
>       This is an intermediate operation.

I would appreciate if somebody created some simple real-life examples about `flatMap`, how you could code it in previous java versions `Java[6,7]` and how you can code the same routines using `Java 8`.

Comment: There are about a million examples of using flatMap (for Scala at least, and they are basically the same :)) on the internet, have you tried searching? Heres one to start with: http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/

Comment: i do not understand Scala i have never have worked with scala

Comment: What I mean is that flatMap is a general concept which now exists in Java as well as Scala.

Comment: ok i will read more about it thanks man.

Comment: flatMap in Java is the same idea but looks quite different with streams. Don't point people to Scala!

Comment: Please look at :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/difference-between-map-and-flatmap-methods-in-java-8/37080387#37080387

Answer (score 164, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to `flatMap` a [Stream](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) that's already flat, like the `Stream<Integer>` you've shown in your question.

However, if you had a `Stream<List<Integer>>` then it would make sense and you could do this:

```
Stream<List<Integer>> integerListStream = Stream.of(
    Arrays.asList(1, 2), 
    Arrays.asList(3, 4), 
    Arrays.asList(5)
);

Stream<Integer> integerStream = integerListStream .flatMap(Collection::stream);
integerStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which would print:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

To do this pre-Java 8 you just need a loops:

```
List<List<Integer>> integerLists = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList(1, 2), 
    Arrays.asList(3, 4), 
    Arrays.asList(5)
)

List<Integer> flattened = new ArrayList<>();

for (List<Integer> integerList : integerLists) {
    flattened.addAll(integerList);
}

for (Integer i : flattened) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: I can't wrap my mind around the Collection::stream inside the flatMap. Why would I need to stream() the elements inside the flatMap if flatMap already returns a stream? 

In my mind doing integerListStream.flatMap(Collection::stream) would return Stream<Stream<Integer>> because I'm calling stream() for each Integer and then returning a Stream of it.... My head hurts

Comment: The `Function` passed to `flatMap` is responsible for creating the `Stream`, so the example I give is really shorthand for `integerListStream .flatMap(ints -> ints.stream())` where `ints` are the lists of integers from `integerLists`.

Answer (score 119):

### Made up example

Imagine that you want to create the following sequence: 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4 etc. (in other words: 1x1, 2x2, 3x3 etc.)

With `flatMap` it could look like:

```
IntStream sequence = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4)
                          .flatMap(i -> IntStream.iterate(i, identity()).limit(i));
sequence.forEach(System.out::println);
```

where:

- `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4)` creates a stream of `int` from 1 to 4, inclusive
- `IntStream.iterate(i, identity()).limit(i)` creates a stream of length i of `int` i - so applied to `i = 4` it creates a stream: `4, 4, 4, 4`
- `flatMap` "flattens" the stream and "concatenates" it to the original stream

With Java < 8 you would need two nested loops:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
}
```

### Real world example

Let's say I have a `List<TimeSeries>` where each `TimeSeries` is essentially a `Map<LocalDate, Double>`. I want to get a list of all dates for which at least one of the time series has a value. `flatMap` to the rescue:

```
list.stream().parallel()
    .flatMap(ts -> ts.dates().stream()) // for each TS, stream dates and flatmap
    .distinct()                         // remove duplicates
    .sorted()                           // sort ascending
    .collect(toList());
```

Not only is it readable, but if you suddenly need to process 100k elements, simply adding `parallel()` will improve performance without you writing any concurrent code.

Comment: Both examples are much better than in the accepted answer.

Comment: compiler complains about *identity()* as _undefined_

Comment: @user3320018 you need to static import `Function.identity`.

Comment: @assylias I tried *import java.util.function.Function* but didn't work, I am new to java 8 and this may or may not be java 8 specific but can you please tell me exactly how to remove that error.

Comment: `import static java.util.function.Function.identity;`

Answer (score 22):

Extract unique words sorted ASC from a list of phrases:

```
List<String> phrases = Arrays.asList(
        "sporadic perjury",
        "confounded skimming",
        "incumbent jailer",
        "confounded jailer");

List<String> uniqueWords = phrases
        .stream()
        .flatMap(phrase -> Stream.of(phrase.split("\\s+")))
        .distinct()
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Unique words: " + uniqueWords);
```

... and the output:

```
Unique words: [confounded, incumbent, jailer, perjury, skimming, sporadic]
```

Answer (score 11):

Am I the only one who finds unwinding lists boring? ;-)

Let's try with objects. Real world example by the way.

Given: Object representing repetitive task. About important task fields: reminders are starting to ring at `start` and repeat every `repeatPeriod` `repeatUnit`(e.g. 5 HOURS) and there will be `repeatCount` reminders in total(including starting one).

Goal: achieve a list of task copies, one for each task reminder invocation.

```
List<Task> tasks =
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Task(
                            false,//completed sign
                            "My important task",//task name (text)
                            LocalDateTime.now().plus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS),//first reminder(start)
                            true,//is task repetitive?
                            1,//reminder interval
                            ChronoUnit.DAYS,//interval unit
                            5//total number of reminders
                    )
            );

tasks.stream().flatMap(
        x -> LongStream.iterate(
                x.getStart().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC),
                p -> (p + x.getRepeatPeriod()*x.getRepeatUnit().getDuration().getSeconds())
        ).limit(x.getRepeatCount()).boxed()
        .map( y -> new Task(x,LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(y,0,ZoneOffset.UTC)))
).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output:**

```
Task{completed=false, text='My important task', start=2014-10-01T21:35:24, repeat=false, repeatCount=0, repeatPeriod=0, repeatUnit=null}
Task{completed=false, text='My important task', start=2014-10-02T21:35:24, repeat=false, repeatCount=0, repeatPeriod=0, repeatUnit=null}
Task{completed=false, text='My important task', start=2014-10-03T21:35:24, repeat=false, repeatCount=0, repeatPeriod=0, repeatUnit=null}
Task{completed=false, text='My important task', start=2014-10-04T21:35:24, repeat=false, repeatCount=0, repeatPeriod=0, repeatUnit=null}
Task{completed=false, text='My important task', start=2014-10-05T21:35:24, repeat=false, repeatCount=0, repeatPeriod=0, repeatUnit=null}
```

P.S.: I would appreciate if someone suggested a simpler solution, I'm not a pro after all.

**UPDATE:**
@RBz asked for detailed explanation so here it is.
Basically flatMap puts all elements from streams inside another stream into output stream. A lot of streams here :). So, for each Task in initial stream lambda expression `x -> LongStream.iterate...` creates a stream of long values that represent task start moments. This stream is limited to `x.getRepeatCount()` instances. It's values start from `x.getStart().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)` and each next value is calculated using lambda `p -> (p + x.getRepeatPeriod()*x.getRepeatUnit().getDuration().getSeconds()`. `boxed()` returns the stream with each long value as a Long wrapper instance. Then each Long in that stream is mapped to new Task instance that is not repetitive anymore and contains exact execution time. This sample contains only one Task in input list. But imagine that you have a thousand. You will have then a stream of 1000 streams of Task objects. And what `flatMap` does here is putting all Tasks from all streams onto the same output stream. That's all as I understand it. Thank you for your question!

Comment: `Am I the only one who finds unwinding lists boring?` +1

Comment: I find it really hard to understand this example. :(

Comment: @RBz Stream operations are sometimes not easy to understand  especially if there's more than one operation involved. It's a matter of practice though. Best you can do is to google every unclear word from the sample and try to use it yourself. In fact the usual imperative style sample would have been much easier to understand(and sometimes faster). So just think if  you really need to use streams.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man. However i am quite ok with the streams concepts. What i am having trouble here is example specific. I was not so good with Time api, but even a read through it is not helping me understanding what is happening here. May be i am being naive, but it will be great to have a little more explanation for your answer. It would really help me in understanding your example. I know, I am just locked to it in curiosity! :)

Comment: Amazing example... a bit hard to understand in the beginning, but once I run it in my IDE... so powerful alternative !!
thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

This method takes one Function as an argument, this function accepts one parameter T as an input argument and return one stream of parameter R as a return value. When this function is applied on each element of this stream, it produces a stream of new values. All the elements of these new streams generated by each element are then copied to a new stream, which will be a return value of this method.

http://codedestine.com/java-8-stream-flatmap-method/

Answer (score 2):

A very simple example: Split a list of full names to get a list of names, regardless of first or last

```
 List<String> fullNames = Arrays.asList("Barry Allen", "Bruce Wayne", "Clark Kent");

 fullNames.stream()
            .flatMap(fullName -> Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(fullName))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This prints out:

```
Barry
Allen
Bruce
Wayne
Clark
Kent
```

Answer (score 1):

Given this:

```
  public class SalesTerritory
    {
        private String territoryName;
        private Set<String> geographicExtents;

        public SalesTerritory( String territoryName, Set<String> zipCodes )
        {
            this.territoryName = territoryName;
            this.geographicExtents = zipCodes;
        }

        public String getTerritoryName()
        {
            return territoryName;
        }

        public void setTerritoryName( String territoryName )
        {
            this.territoryName = territoryName;
        }

        public Set<String> getGeographicExtents()
        {
            return geographicExtents != null ? Collections.unmodifiableSet( geographicExtents ) : Collections.emptySet();
        }

        public void setGeographicExtents( Set<String> geographicExtents )
        {
            this.geographicExtents = new HashSet<>( geographicExtents );
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode()
        {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode( this.territoryName );
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals( Object obj )
        {
            if ( this == obj ) {
                return true;
            }
            if ( obj == null ) {
                return false;
            }
            if ( getClass() != obj.getClass() ) {
                return false;
            }
            final SalesTerritory other = (SalesTerritory) obj;
            if ( !Objects.equals( this.territoryName, other.territoryName ) ) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "SalesTerritory{" + "territoryName=" + territoryName + ", geographicExtents=" + geographicExtents + '}';
        }

    }
```

and this:

```
public class SalesTerritories
{
    private static final Set<SalesTerritory> territories
        = new HashSet<>(
            Arrays.asList(
                new SalesTerritory[]{
                    new SalesTerritory( "North-East, USA",
                                        new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( new String[]{ "Maine", "New Hampshire", "Vermont",
                                                                                    "Rhode Island", "Massachusetts", "Connecticut",
                                                                                    "New York", "New Jersey", "Delaware", "Maryland",
                                                                                    "Eastern Pennsylvania", "District of Columbia" } ) ) ),
                    new SalesTerritory( "Appalachia, USA",
                                        new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( new String[]{ "West-Virgina", "Kentucky",
                                                                                    "Western Pennsylvania" } ) ) ),
                    new SalesTerritory( "South-East, USA",
                                        new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( new String[]{ "Virginia", "North Carolina", "South Carolina",
                                                                                    "Georgia", "Florida", "Alabama", "Tennessee",
                                                                                    "Mississippi", "Arkansas", "Louisiana" } ) ) ),
                    new SalesTerritory( "Mid-West, USA",
                                        new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( new String[]{ "Ohio", "Michigan", "Wisconsin", "Minnesota",
                                                                                    "Iowa", "Missouri", "Illinois", "Indiana" } ) ) ),
                    new SalesTerritory( "Great Plains, USA",
                                        new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( new String[]{ "Oklahoma", "Kansas", "Nebraska",
                                                                                    "South Dakota", "North Dakota",
                                                                                    "Eastern Montana",
                                                                                    "Wyoming", "Colorada" } ) ) ),
                    new SalesTerritory( "Rocky Mountain, USA",
                                        new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( new String[]{ "Western Montana", "Idaho", "Utah", "Nevada" } ) ) ),
                    new SalesTerritory( "South-West, USA",
                                        new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( new String[]{ "Arizona", "New Mexico", "Texas" } ) ) ),
                    new SalesTerritory( "Pacific North-West, USA",
                                        new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( new String[]{ "Washington", "Oregon", "Alaska" } ) ) ),
                    new SalesTerritory( "Pacific South-West, USA",
                                        new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( new String[]{ "California", "Hawaii" } ) ) )
                }
            )
        );

    public static Set<SalesTerritory> getAllTerritories()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet( territories );
    }

    private SalesTerritories()
    {
    }

}
```

We can then do this:

```
System.out.println();
System.out
    .println( "We can use 'flatMap' in combination with the 'AbstractMap.SimpleEntry' class to flatten a hierarchical data-structure to a set of Key/Value pairs..." );
SalesTerritories.getAllTerritories()
    .stream()
    .flatMap( t -> t.getGeographicExtents()
        .stream()
        .map( ge -> new SimpleEntry<>( t.getTerritoryName(), ge ) )
    )
    .map( e -> String.format( "%-30s : %s",
                              e.getKey(),
                              e.getValue() ) )
    .forEach( System.out::println );
```