# What's the difference between map() and flatMap() methods in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In Java 8, what's the difference between [`Stream.map()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [`Stream.flatMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) methods?

Comment: The type signature kinda tells the whole story. `map :: Stream T -> (T -> R) -> Stream R`, `flatMap :: Stream T -> (T -> Stream R) -> Stream R`.

Comment: fwiw, those type signatures don't even look like Java. (I know, I know -- but to say it tells "the whole story" wrt map/flatMap assumes a lot of knowledge about the new & improved "Java++")

Comment: @michael That type signature looks like Haskell, not Java. But it's not clear whether the actual Java signature is any more readable: `<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)`.

Comment: Ha, yeah, I was referring to the "actual Java". Like C++, modern Java is almost unrecognizable to anyone who started using it in the 90s (like I did, both languages). Just replying to the comment, that method signatures hardly tell a "whole story", at least not anymore, not without additional exposition (or in that commenters case, translation).

Comment: Which is to say, a `map`'s mapper lambda returns `R`, a `flatMap`'s mapper lambda returns a `Stream` of `R` (`Stream<R>`). The streams returned by the `flatMap`'s mapper are effectively concatenated. Otherwise, both `map` and `flatMap` return `Stream<R>`; the difference is what the mapper lambdas return, `R` vs. `Stream<R>`.

Comment: Use `map` if each element is transformed into a single value. Use `flatMap` if each element will be transformed to multiple values and the resulting stream needs to be flattened.

Answer (score 1049, accepted):

Both `map` and `flatMap` can be applied to a `Stream<T>` and they both return a `Stream<R>`. The difference is that the `map` operation produces one output value for each input value, whereas the `flatMap` operation produces an arbitrary number (zero or more) values for each input value.

This is reflected in the arguments to each operation.

The `map` operation takes a `Function`, which is called for each value in the input stream and produces one result value, which is sent to the output stream.

The `flatMap` operation takes a function that conceptually wants to consume one value and produce an arbitrary number of values. However, in Java, it's cumbersome for a method to return an arbitrary number of values, since methods can return only zero or one value. One could imagine an API where the mapper function for `flatMap` takes a value and returns an array or a `List` of values, which are then sent to the output. Given that this is the streams library, a particularly apt way to represent an arbitrary number of return values is for the mapper function itself to return a stream! The values from the stream returned by the mapper are drained from the stream and are passed to the output stream. The "clumps" of values returned by each call to the mapper function are not distinguished at all in the output stream, thus the output is said to have been "flattened."

Typical use is for the mapper function of `flatMap` to return `Stream.empty()` if it wants to send zero values, or something like `Stream.of(a, b, c)` if it wants to return several values. But of course any stream can be returned.

Comment: Sounds to me like the `flatMap` operation is the exact opposite of flat. Yet again, leave it to Computer Scientists to turn a term on it's head. Like a function being "transparent" meaning you can't see anything it does, just the results, while colloquially saying you want a process to be transparent means you want every part of it to be seen.

Comment: @coladict Try viewing it from a different perspective: it's not a transparent case where you can see the inner workings through, but the whole function itself is transparent, i.e. invisible, to you - while still doing their work and letting you see what you're working with. In this case, "flat" refers to the opposite of "nested", flatmap removes one nesting level by flattening.

Comment: @coladict The "transparent" thing has been eating my head for years. Glad to know at least one other person feels the same way.

Comment: @coladict: i was just thinking along the same line where does the flat part in the name come from?

Comment: Flattening comes from turning 2-level structure into single level structure, see Dici's answer for an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/26684582/6012102

Comment: This is the best explanation of **flatMap**. This is what makes it all clicked: *The values from the stream returned by the mapper are drained from the stream and are passed to the output stream. The "clumps" of values returned by each call to the mapper function are not distinguished at all in the output stream, thus the output is said to have been "flattened"*. Thank you!

Comment: @coladict
@markus

If you provided the same transformer method to `map` instead of `flatMap`, you would have a `Stream<Stream<R>>` instead of just a `Stream<R>`

https://gist.github.com/bradynpoulsen/f3f5458d718a996c5b3dec9decefb6d2

Comment: @Zefiro would not the work "opaque" that better then?

Comment: @PålOliver Possibly. But people seem to like transparency, so the same word is used for two different meanings, depending on whether you're interested in seeing the inner mechanism (so the box around it is transparent for it to be seen) or don't want their view blocked by those details (so the whole mechanism is see-through).

Comment: I would rather say  FlatMap == Map+FaltteningTheResults

Comment: Great answer, another typical usage would be using flatMap on an Optional, if the passed lambda returns an Optional too.

Comment: Another advantage of using streams within the result: they can be lazily calculated, in case of large or expensive to compute streams.  So if each item of the initial stream returns, say, a million records that are easily calculated, you don't need to have all million records in memory at once: the stream function can generate them as they are processed.

Answer (score 827):

`Stream.flatMap`, as it can be guessed by its name, is the combination of a `map` and a `flat` operation. That means that you first apply a function to your elements, and then flatten it. `Stream.map` only applies a function to the stream without flattening the stream.

To understand what *flattening* a stream consists in, consider a structure like `[ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ]` which has "two levels". Flattening this means transforming it in a "one level" structure : `[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ]`.

Comment: Haha, to be fair I'm still surprised to see how much traffic this question gets. Another funny observation is that it's been almost 5 years I wrote this answer and there's been a fairly consistent pattern of upvoting where the accepted answer gets roughly two upvotes for every one my answer gets. It's surprisingly consistent.

Comment: how is this not the accepted answer, thank for getting straight to the point and putting a very simple example

Comment: I believe this answer is concise and logically better explained than the accepted one.

Comment: This answer is short and practical. The accepted (Stuart's) answer added an explanation on _why is that kind of method (`flatMap`) needed?_ Each answer cater for different types of answer that the community may seek.

Comment: sleek way of explaining

Comment: What is the use case of the flatMap? At the end I just want to collect it so I do not see why flatten it if at the end it will be a list or another collection, performance? map.collect vs flatMap.collect

Comment: If you collect it without flattening you'll get a list of lists (for example), which is not as easy to manipulate if all you care about are the values in the lists. If each list represents stronger concept like a cart of items or something like that, then keeping the items grouped in separate collections can make sense.

Answer (score 319):

I would like to give 2 examples to get a *more* practical point of view:

First example making usage of `map`:

```java
@Test
public void convertStringToUpperCaseStreams() {
    List<String> collected = Stream.of("a", "b", "hello") // Stream of String 
            .map(String::toUpperCase) // Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    assertEquals(asList("A", "B", "HELLO"), collected);
}
```

Nothing special in the first example, a `Function` is applied to return the `String` in uppercase.

Second example making usage of `flatMap`:

```java
@Test
public void testflatMap() throws Exception {
    List<Integer> together = Stream.of(asList(1, 2), asList(3, 4)) // Stream of List<Integer>
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .map(integer -> integer + 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    assertEquals(asList(2, 3, 4, 5), together);
}
```

In the second example, a Stream of List is passed. **It is NOT a Stream of Integer!**

***If a transformation Function has to be used (through map), then first the Stream has to be flattened to something else (a Stream of Integer).***

If `flatMap` is removed then the following error is returned: **The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) List, int.**

It is NOT possible to apply + 1 on a `List` of Integers!

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar I think you would end up with a Stream of `Stream<Integer>` rather than a Stream of `Integer`.

Answer (score 207):

***Please go through the post fully to get a clear idea,***

**map vs flatMap:**

To return a length  of each word from a list, we would do something like below..

### Short Version given below

**When we collect two lists, given below**

***Without*** flat map => **[1,2],[1,1]** => **[[1,2],[1,1]]** Here two lists are placed inside a list, so the output will be list containing lists

***With*** flat map => **[1,2],[1,1]** => **[1,2,1,1]** Here two lists are flattened and only the values are placed in list, so the output will be list containing only elements

**Basically it merges all the objects in to one**

## Detailed Version has been given below:-

**For example:-** 
Consider a list **[“STACK”, ”OOOVVVER”]** and we are trying to return a list like **[“STACKOVER”]**(returning only unique letters from that list)
Initially, we would do something like below to return a list  **[“STACKOVER”]**  from  **[“STACK”, ”OOOVVVER”]**

```
public class WordMap {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> lst = Arrays.asList("STACK","OOOVER");
    lst.stream().map(w->w.split("")).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

Here the issue is, Lambda passed to the map method returns a String array for each word, So the stream returned by the map method is actually of type Stream, But what we need is Stream to represent a stream of characters, below image illustrates the problem.

**Figure A:**

[image]

You might think that, We can resolve this problem using flatmap,
 OK, let us see how to solve this by using *map* and *Arrays.stream*
First of all you gonna need a stream of characters instead of a stream of arrays. There is a method called Arrays.stream() that would take an array and produces a stream, for example:

```
String[] arrayOfWords = {"STACK", "OOOVVVER"};
Stream<String> streamOfWords = Arrays.stream(arrayOfWords);
streamOfWords.map(s->s.split("")) //Converting word in to array of letters
    .map(Arrays::stream).distinct() //Make array in to separate stream
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above still does not work, because we now end up with a list of streams (more precisely, Stream>), Instead, we must first convert each word into an array of individual letters and then make each array into a separate stream

**By using flatMap we should be able to fix this problem as below:**

```
String[] arrayOfWords = {"STACK", "OOOVVVER"};
Stream<String> streamOfWords = Arrays.stream(arrayOfWords);
streamOfWords.map(s->s.split("")) //Converting word in to array of letters
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream).distinct() //flattens each generated stream in to a single stream
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

flatMap would perform mapping each array not with stream but with the contents of that stream. All of the individual streams that would get generated while using map(Arrays::stream) get merged into a single stream. Figure B illustrates the effect of using the flatMap method. Compare it with what map does in figure A.
**Figure B**
[image]

**The flatMap method lets you replace each value of a stream with another stream and then joins all the generated streams into a single stream.**

Comment: Nice diagrammatic explanation.

Comment: @TechDog I appreciate your example. I was stuck trying to find how to split up lines into words and stream them.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation based on practical examples with illustrations. It's very helpful for understanding.

Answer (score 159):

**One line answer: `flatMap` helps to flatten a `Collection<Collection<T>>` into a `Collection<T>`**. In the same way, it will also flatten an **`Optional<Optional<T>>`** into **`Optional<T>`**.

[image]

As you can see, with **`map()`** only:

- The intermediate type is `Stream<List<Item>>`
- The return type is `List<List<Item>>`

and with **`flatMap()`**:

- The intermediate type is `Stream<Item>`
- The return type is `List<Item>`

This is the **test result** from the code used right below:

```
-------- Without flatMap() -------------------------------
     collect() returns: [[Laptop, Phone], [Mouse, Keyboard]]

-------- With flatMap() ----------------------------------
     collect() returns: [Laptop, Phone, Mouse, Keyboard]
```

**Code used**:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Parcel {
  String name;
  List<String> items;

  public Parcel(String name, String... items) {
    this.name = name;
    this.items = Arrays.asList(items);
  }

  public List<String> getItems() {
    return items;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parcel amazon = new Parcel("amazon", "Laptop", "Phone");
    Parcel ebay = new Parcel("ebay", "Mouse", "Keyboard");
    List<Parcel> parcels = Arrays.asList(amazon, ebay);

    System.out.println("-------- Without flatMap() ---------------------------");
    List<List<String>> mapReturn = parcels.stream()
      .map(Parcel::getItems)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("\t collect() returns: " + mapReturn);

    System.out.println("\n-------- With flatMap() ------------------------------");
    List<String> flatMapReturn = parcels.stream()
      .map(Parcel::getItems)
      .flatMap(Collection::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("\t collect() returns: " + flatMapReturn);
  }
}
```

Comment: Very crisp example.., Wouldn't take more than few secs to understand the concept with your example...

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that Optional<Optional<T>>  to Optional<T>. Otherwise, it would've been answer by me!

Answer (score 59):

### **.map** is for ***`A -> B`*** mapping

```
Stream.of("dog", "cat")              // stream of 2 Strings
    .map(s -> s.length())            // stream of 2 Integers: [3, 3]
```

*it converts any item `A` to any item `B`. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function))*

---

### **.flatMap** is for ***`A -> Stream< B>`*** concatinating

```
Stream.of("dog", "cat")             // stream of 2 Strings
    .flatMapToInt(s -> s.chars())   // stream of 6 ints:      [d, o, g, c, a, t]
```

*it --1 converts any item `A` into `Stream< B>`, then --2 concatenates all the streams into one (flat) stream. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function))*

---

Note 1: Although the latter example flats to a stream of primitives (IntStream) instead of a stream of objects (Stream), it still illustrates the idea of the `.flatMap`.

Note 2: Despite the name, String.chars() method returns ints. So the actual collection will be: `[100, 111, 103, 99, 97, 116]`
, where `100` is the code of `'d'`, `111` is the code of `'o'` etc. Again, for illustrative purposes, it's presented as [d, o, g, c, a, t].

Comment: just replace with toCharArray and make your post shorter.

Answer (score 54):

The function you pass to `stream.map` has to return one object. That means each object in the input stream results in exactly one object in the output stream.

The function you pass to `stream.flatMap` returns a stream for each object. That means the function can return any number of objects for each input object (including none). The resulting streams are then concatenated to one output stream.

Comment: Why would you want to "return any number of objects for each input object (including none)"?

Comment: @DerekMahar There would be plenty of use-cases for this. For example, let's say you have a stream of `Department`s in your organization. Each department has between 0 and n `Employee`s. What you need is a stream of all employees. So what do you do? You write a flatMap method which takes a department and returns a stream of its employees.

Comment: Philipp, does your example illustrate the main reason to use `flatMap`?  I suspect that it may be incidental and doesn't illustrate the key use case or reason why `flatMap` exists.  (Continued below...)

Comment: After reading https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-flatmap, I think the main motivation behind `flatMap` is to accommodate errors that would be present when using `map`.  How do you handle cases where one or more items in the original set cannot be mapped to an output item?  By introducing an intermediate set (say an `Optional` or `Stream`) for each input object, `flatMap` allows you to exclude the "invalid" input objects (or the so called "bad apples" in the spirit of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52248643/107158) from the final set.

Comment: @DerekMahar Yes, stuations where each input-object might or might not return an output-object is another good use-case for flat-map.

Comment: @DerekMahar Although usually you would use the method `stream.filter` for that.

Answer (score 39):

for a Map we have a list of elements and a (function,action) f so :

```
[a,b,c] f(x) => [f(a),f(b),f(c)]
```

and for the flat map we have a list of elements list and we have a (function,action) f and we want the result to be flattened :

```
[[a,b],[c,d,e]] f(x) =>[f(a),f(b),f(c),f(d),f(e)]
```

Answer (score 32):

I have a feeling that most answers here overcomplicate the simple problem. If you already understand how the `map` works that should be fairly easy to grasp.

There are cases where we can end up with unwanted nested structures when using `map()`, the `flatMap()` method is designed to overcome this by avoiding wrapping.

---

Examples:

## 1

```
List<List<Integer>> result = Stream.of(Arrays.asList(1), Arrays.asList(2, 3))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

We can avoid having nested lists by using `flatMap`:

```
List<Integer> result = Stream.of(Arrays.asList(1), Arrays.asList(2, 3))
  .flatMap(i -> i.stream())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

## 2

```
Optional<Optional<String>> result = Optional.of(42)
      .map(id -> findById(id));

Optional<String> result = Optional.of(42)
      .flatMap(id -> findById(id));
```

where:

```
private Optional<String> findById(Integer id)
```

Comment: sorry but the 2nd snippet from point 1 is not compiling instead of  `List<Integer> result = Stream.of(Arrays.asList(1), Arrays.asList(2, 3))
  .flatMap(i -> i)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());` . It is should be `Stream.of(Arrays.asList(1), Arrays.asList(2, 3))
      .flatMap(List::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @arthur I think I used Vavr's Stream and List here - but I agree that it might be confusing a bit - I will change that to standard Java

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek  [how about this simple explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52248643/1059372) ?

Answer (score 32):

**map() and flatMap()**

1. `map()`

Just takes a Function <T, R> a lambda param where T is element and R the return element built using T. At the end we'll have a Stream with objects of Type R. A simple example can be:

```
Stream
  .of(1,2,3,4,5)
  .map(myInt -> "preFix_"+myInt)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It simply takes elements 1 to 5 of Type `Integer`, uses each element to build a new element from type `String` with value `"prefix_"+integer_value` and prints it out.

2. `flatMap()`

It is useful to know that flatMap() takes a function `F<T, R>` where

- T is a type from *which a Stream can be built from/with*. It can be a List (T.stream()), an array (Arrays.stream(someArray)), etc.. anything that from which a Stream can be with/or form. in the example below each dev has many languages, so dev. Languages is a List and will use a lambda parameter.
- R is the resulting Stream that will be built using T. Knowing that we have many instances of T, we will naturally have many Streams from R. All these Streams from Type R will **now be combined into one** single 'flat' Stream from Type R.

**Example**

The examples of Bachiri Taoufiq  [see its answer here] [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627214/755401) are simple and easy to understanding. Just for clarity, let just say we have a team of developers:

```
dev_team = {dev_1,dev_2,dev_3}
```

, with each developer knowing  many languages:

```
dev_1 = {lang_a,lang_b,lang_c},
dev_2 = {lang_d},
dev_3 = {lang_e,lang_f}
```

Applying  *Stream.map()* on dev_team to get the languages of each dev:

```
dev_team.map(dev -> dev.getLanguages())
```

will give you this structure:

```
{ 
  {lang_a,lang_b,lang_c},
  {lang_d},
  {lang_e,lang_f}
}
```

which is basically a `List<List<Languages>> /Object[Languages[]]`. Not so very pretty, nor Java8-like!!

with `Stream.flatMap()` you can 'flatten' things out as it takes the above structure
and turns it into `{lang_a, lang_b, lang_c, lang_d, lang_e, lang_f}`, which can basically used as `List<Languages>/Language[]/etc`...

so in the end, your code would make more sense like this:

```
dev_team
   .stream()    /* {dev_1,dev_2,dev_3} */
   .map(dev -> dev.getLanguages()) /* {{lang_a,...,lang_c},{lang_d}{lang_e,lang_f}}} */
   .flatMap(languages ->  languages.stream()) /* {lang_a,...,lang_d, lang_e, lang_f} */
   .doWhateverWithYourNewStreamHere();
```

or simply:

```
dev_team
       .stream()    /* {dev_1,dev_2,dev_3} */
       .flatMap(dev -> dev.getLanguages().stream()) /* {lang_a,...,lang_d, lang_e, lang_f} */
       .doWhateverWithYourNewStreamHere();
```

**When to use map() and use flatMap()**:

- Use `map()` when each element of type T from your stream is supposed to be mapped/transformed to a *single* element of type R. The result is a mapping of type *(1 start element -> 1 end element)* and new stream of elements of type R is returned.
- Use `flatMap()` when each element of type T from your stream is supposed to mapped/transformed to a *Collections* of elements of type R. The result is a mapping of type *(1 start element -> n end elements)*. These Collections are then *merged* (or *flattened*) to a new stream of elements of type R. This is useful for example to represent **nested loops**.

Pre Java 8:

```
List<Foo> myFoos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    for(Foo foo: myFoos){
        for(Bar bar:  foo.getMyBars()){
            System.out.println(bar.getMyName());
        }
    }
```

Post Java 8

```
myFoos
    .stream()
    .flatMap(foo -> foo.getMyBars().stream())
    .forEach(bar -> System.out.println(bar.getMyName()));
```

Answer (score 25):

Oracle's article on Optional highlights this difference between map and flatmap:

```
String version = computer.map(Computer::getSoundcard)
                  .map(Soundcard::getUSB)
                  .map(USB::getVersion)
                  .orElse("UNKNOWN");
```

> Unfortunately, this code doesn't compile. Why? The variable computer
>   is of type `Optional<Computer>`, so it is perfectly correct to call the
>   map method. However, getSoundcard() returns an object of type
>   Optional. This means the result of the map operation is an
>   object of type `Optional<Optional<Soundcard>>`. As a result, the call to
>   getUSB() is invalid because the outermost Optional contains as its
>   value another Optional, which of course doesn't support the getUSB()
>   method.
>
> With streams, the flatMap method takes a function as an argument,
>   which returns another stream. This function is applied to each element
>   of a stream, which would result in a stream of streams. However,
>   flatMap has the effect of replacing each generated stream by the
>   contents of that stream. In other words, all the separate streams that
>   are generated by the function get amalgamated or "flattened" into one
>   single stream. What we want here is something similar, but **we want to
>   "flatten" a two-level Optional into one**.
>
> Optional also supports a flatMap method. Its purpose is to apply
>   the transformation function on the value of an Optional (just like the map
>   operation does) and then **flatten the resulting two-level Optional into
>   a single one**.
>
> So, to make our code correct, we need to rewrite it as follows using
>   flatMap:

```
String version = computer.flatMap(Computer::getSoundcard)
                   .flatMap(Soundcard::getUSB)
                   .map(USB::getVersion)
                   .orElse("UNKNOWN");
```

> The first flatMap ensures that an `Optional<Soundcard>` is returned
>   instead of an `Optional<Optional<Soundcard>>`, and the second flatMap
>   achieves the same purpose to return an `Optional<USB>`. Note that the
>   third call just needs to be a map() because getVersion() returns a
>   String rather than an Optional object.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Comment: the question was about Stream.map and Stream.flatMap & not about Optional.map anfd Optional.flatMap

Comment: But it helped me a lot to understand my problems with optional and flatmap, thanks a lot!

Comment: @djames, it's a perfectly valid answer, read it starting from paragraph "With streams, the flatMap method takes a function as an argument..." :)

Comment: flatMap() version also throws nullpointerexception if soundCard is null. So where's the promised benefit of Optional?

Comment: @Ekaterina, that's the pointer of working with `Optional`s, if the `getter`s return `Optional`s, then now `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 19):

I am not very sure I am supposed to answer this, but every time I face someone that does not understand this, I use the same example.

Imagine you have an apple. A `map` is transforming that apple to `apple-juice` for example or a *one-to-one* mapping.

Take that same apple and get only the seeds out of it, that is what `flatMap` does, or a *one to many*, one apple as input, many seeds as output.

Comment: For the `flatMap` case, do you first collect the seeds from each apple in separate bags, one bag per apple, before you pour all of the bags into a single bag?

Comment: @DerekMahar it used to be a poor into a single bag before java-10, meaning `flatmap` was not really lazy, but since java-10 it is lazy

Comment: @Eugene please explain a little more lazy concept which you are trying to explain not clear to me.i understood what derkerMahar explained in comment is it that what happening before java10?

Comment: @JAVA just search `flatMap + lazy`, I bet there will be some answers.

Comment: @Eugene - The flatMap will take one apple at a time, extract its seeds and throw it into a bag/collection/array until all the apples seeds have been extracted. Right ? Is that how streams work ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 it depends on the java version, really.

Comment: @MasterJoe2 it seems like you have a specific question in mind, why not post it?

Comment: @Eugene - I have posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60539486/is-my-understanding-of-java-stream-flatmap-correct

Comment: @Eugene I don't understand. seeds are different from juice. As I understand, flat map is supposed to reduce multiple streams to a single stream. I wonder if your analogy is incorrect.

Answer (score 14):

Map:- 
This method takes one Function as an argument and returns a new stream consisting of the results generated by applying the passed function to all the elements of the stream.

Let's imagine, I have a list of integer values ( 1,2,3,4,5 ) and one function interface whose logic is square of the passed integer. ( e -> e * e ).

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

List<Integer> newList = intList.stream().map( e -> e * e ).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(newList);
```

output:-

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

As you can see, an output is a new stream whose values are square of values of the input stream.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> apply e -> e * e -> [ 1*1, 2*2, 3*3, 4*4, 5*5 ] -> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25 ]
```

http://codedestine.com/java-8-stream-map-method/

FlatMap :- 
This method takes one Function as an argument, this function accepts one parameter T as an input argument and returns one stream of parameter R as a return value. When this function is applied to each element of this stream, it produces a stream of new values. All the elements of these new streams generated by each element are then copied to a new stream, which will be a return value of this method.

Let's image, I have a list of student objects, where each student can opt for multiple subjects.

```
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

  studentList.add(new Student("Robert","5st grade", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"history","math","geography"})));
  studentList.add(new Student("Martin","8st grade", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"economics","biology"})));
  studentList.add(new Student("Robert","9st grade", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"science","math"})));

  Set<Student> courses = studentList.stream().flatMap( e -> e.getCourse().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

  System.out.println(courses);
```

output:-

```
[economics, biology, geography, science, history, math]
```

As you can see, an output is a new stream whose values are a collection of all the elements of the streams return by each element of the input stream.

[ S1 , S2 , S3 ]  ->
[ {"history","math","geography"}, {"economics","biology"}, {"science","math"} ] -> take unique subjects ->
[economics, biology, geography, science, history, math]

http://codedestine.com/java-8-stream-flatmap-method/

Comment: could make a difference if you provide code instead of just provinding doc link

Comment: you type is incorrect right?   Set<Student> courses = studentList.stream().flatMap( e -> e.getCourse().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
 should be a set of string here?

Answer (score 12):

By reading all the messages, the simple way to understand is :

- use `map` if you have a `flat` list of elements: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
- use `flatMap` if you have a list of list of elements: [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]. This means that, your list need to be **flattened** before the **map** operation can be applied to each elements

Answer (score 8):

If you think `map()` as an iteration(one level `for` loop), `flatmap()` is a two-level iteration(like a nested `for` loop). (Enter each iterated element `foo`, and do `foo.getBarList()` and iterate in that `barList` again)

---

`map()`: take a stream, do something to every element, collect the single result of every process, output another stream. The definition of "do something function" is implicit. If the processment of any element results in `null`, `null` is used to compose the final stream. So, the number of elements in the resulting stream will be equal to number of input stream.

`flatmap()`: take a stream of *elements/streams* and a function(explicit definition), apply the function to each element of each stream, and collect all the intermediate resulting stream to be a greater stream("flattening"). If the processment of any element results in `null`, empty stream is provided to the final step of "flattening". The number of elements in the resulting stream, is the total of all participating elements in all inputs, if the input is several streams.

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer.

The `map` operation can produce a `Stream` of `Stream`.EX `Stream<Stream<Integer>>`

`flatMap` operation will only produce `Stream` of something. EX `Stream<Integer>`

Answer (score 3):

Definitions of these Stream API methods:

**map**(Function mapper) is an intermediate operation which returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

**flatMap**(Function mapper) is an intermediate operation which returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element. In short, it is used to convert a Stream of Stream into a list of values.

Take a look at example:

```
List<String> myList = Stream.of("Apple", "Orange")
       .map(String::toUpperCase)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(myList);
```

It prints: `[APPLE, ORANGE]`

Can we just change `map()` to `flatMap()`?

```
List<String> myListFlat = Stream.of("Apple", "Orange")
       .flatMap(String::toUpperCase)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(myListFlat);
```

No, we can see an error now:

```
java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in method reference
      java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.stream.Stream<? extends R>)
```

Why is that? Take a look at methods signatures:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper);
```

The reason why the code doesn’t work is that the `flatMap()` method expects a function that returns a Stream. In second example, I am passing a method reference to `String.toUpperCase()` which returns a String. Therefore, I am trying to apply `flatMap()` on a Stream of characters instead of a Stream of Strings.

Ok, so now we can have an idea for what `flatMap()` is used.
Let's build a list of lists:

```
List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList("Apple"),
            Arrays.asList("Orange"));
System.out.println(list);
```

and it prints: `[[Apple], [Orange]]`. If we want to have it flatten let's use `flatMap()`:

```
List<String> flattedList = list
                .stream()
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(flattedList);
```

and now it prints: `[Apple, Orange]`

Sources:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-flatmap-java-examples/

https://www.javatpoint.com/flatmap-method-in-java-8

https://www.baeldung.com/java-difference-map-and-flatmap

Answer (score 1):

This is very confusing for beginners. The basic difference is `map` emits one item for each entry in the list and `flatMap` is basically a `map` + `flatten` operation. To be more clear, use flatMap when you require more than one value, eg when you are expecting a loop to return arrays, flatMap will be really helpful in this case.

I have written a blog about this, you can check it out [here](https://blog.expert-talks.in/rx-java/difference-between-map-and-flatmap-rxjava/).

Comment: [how about this simple explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52248643/1059372) ?

Answer (score 1):

Stream operations `flatMap` and `map` accept a function as input.

`flatMap` expects the function to return a new stream for each element of the stream and returns a stream which combines all the elements of the streams returned by the function for each element. In other words, with `flatMap`, for each element from the source, multiple elements will be created by the function. http://www.zoftino.com/java-stream-examples#flatmap-operation

`map` expects the function to return a transformed value and returns a new stream containing the transformed elements. In other words, with `map`, for each element from the source, one transformed element will be created by the function.
http://www.zoftino.com/java-stream-examples#map-operation

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap()` also takes advantage of partial lazy evaluation of streams. It will read the fist stream and only when required, will go to the next stream. The behaviour is explained in detail here: [Is flatMap guaranteed to be lazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288915/is-flatmap-guaranteed-to-be-lazy)

Answer (score 0):

Also good analogy can be with C# if you familiar with. Basically C# `Select` similar to java `map` and C# `SelectMany` java `flatMap`. Same applies to Kotlin for collections.

Answer (score 0):

map() takes a Stream and transform it to another Stream. It applies a function on each element of Stream and store return value into new Stream. It does not flatten the stream. But flatMap() is the combination of a map and a flat operation i.e, it applies a function to elements as well as flatten them.
2) map() is used for transformation only, but flatMap() is used for both transformation and flattening.
please read more here.
https://javaint4bytes.blogspot.com/2022/11/stream-flatmap-in-java-with-examples.html