# What is the difference between Optional.flatMap and Optional.map?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

What's the difference between these two methods: `Optional.flatMap()` and `Optional.map()`?

An example would be appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/java-8-map-and-flatmap-methods

Comment: @AlexisC. Your link is about Stream's map and flatMap, not Optional.

Comment: from the java doc: If a value is present, apply the provided Optional-bearing mapping function to it, return that result, otherwise return an empty Optional. This method is similar to map(Function), but the provided mapper is one whose result is already an Optional, and if invoked, flatMap does not wrap it with an additional Optional.

Comment: @Eran That doesn't matter, if you understand how map/flatMap works whether it's for a Stream or not, it's the same for an Optional. If the op understood how it works for a Stream, then he shouldn't asked this question. The concept is the same.

Comment: @AlexisC. Not really. Optional's flatMap has little in common with Stream's flatMap.

Comment: @Eran I'm speaking about the **conceptual** difference between a map and a flatMap, I'm not making a one-to-one correspondance between `Stream#flatMap` and `Optional#flatMap`.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Use `map` if the function returns the object you need or `flatMap` if the function returns an `Optional`. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Optional<String> s = Optional.of("input");
  System.out.println(s.map(Test::getOutput));
  System.out.println(s.flatMap(Test::getOutputOpt));
}

static String getOutput(String input) {
  return input == null ? null : "output for " + input;
}

static Optional<String> getOutputOpt(String input) {
  return input == null ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of("output for " + input);
}
```

Both print statements print the same thing.

Comment: Question: would `[flat]Map` ever call the mapping function with an `input == null`? My understanding is that `Optional` sortcuts if it's absent - the [JavaDoc ](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) seems to back this up - "_If a value is present, apply ..._".

Comment: @BoristheSpider Optional.of(null) != Optional.empty()

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia `Optional.of(null)` is an `Exception`. `Optional.ofNullable(null) == Optional.empty()`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes, you are right,. I was trying to reply to your question but I think I made it even more unclear: conceptually, Optional.ofNullable(null) should NOT be empty, but in practice it's considered to be, and therefore map/flatmap do not execute.

Comment: I think input should never be null in either getOutputOpt or getOutput

Comment: Now that I've trained with Optional and streams, I feel like I'm writing cleaner code, thanks for the simple comparison. You can really focus on more important things and just wrapping your checks, parsings and throwing exceptions with one liners :) About Optionals, I suggest you to read this awesome small post : https://leanjava.co/2018/02/01/optional-get-is-code-smell/

Comment: Beware! if `s` is empty, then the functions passed to `s.map()` and `s.flatMap()` will not get called.

Comment: Good explanation.

Answer (score 94):

They both take a function from the type of the optional to something.

`map()` applies the function "***as is***" on the optional you have:

```
if (optional.isEmpty()) return Optional.empty();
else return Optional.of(f(optional.get()));
```

What happens if your function is a function from `T -> Optional<U>`?
Your result is now an `Optional<Optional<U>>`!

That's what `flatMap()` is about: if your function already returns an `Optional`, `flatMap()` is a bit smarter and doesn't double wrap it, returning `Optional<U>`.

It's the composition of two functional idioms: `map` and `flatten`.

Answer (score 17):

Okay. You **only need to use 'flatMap' when you're facing nested Optionals**. Here's the example.

```
public class Person {

    private Optional<Car> optionalCar;

    public Optional<Car> getOptionalCar() {
        return optionalCar;
    }
}

public class Car {

    private Optional<Insurance> optionalInsurance;

    public Optional<Insurance> getOptionalInsurance() {
        return optionalInsurance;
    }
}

public class Insurance {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}

public class Test {

    // map cannot deal with nested Optionals
    public Optional<String> getCarInsuranceName(Person person) {
        return person.getOptionalCar()
                .map(Car::getOptionalInsurance) // ① leads to a Optional<Optional<Insurance>
                .map(Insurance::getName);       // ②
    }

}
```

Like Stream, Optional#map will return a value wrapped by a Optional. That's why we get a nested Optional -- `Optional<Optional<Insurance>`. And at ②, we want to map it as an Insurance instance, that's how the tragedy happened.
The root is nested Optionals. If we can get the core value regardless the shells, we'll get it done. That's what flatMap does.

```
public Optional<String> getCarInsuranceName(Person person) {
    return person.getOptionalCar()
                 .flatMap(Car::getOptionalInsurance)
                 .map(Insurance::getName);
}
```

In the end, I stronly recommed the *Java 8 In Action* to you if you'd like to study Java8 Systematicly.

Comment: This answer needs to explicitly state that the example is pulled from Java 8 in Action, just to make sure this doesn't get flagged as unattributed copying.

Answer (score 10):

#### NOTE

Below is the illustration of `map()` and `flatMap()` functions, otherwise `Optional` is primarily designed to be used as a return type only.

---

As you already may know `Optional` is a kind of container which may or may not contain a single object, so it can be used wherever you anticipate a `null` value (you may never see NPE if you use `Optional` properly).

For example if you have a method which expects a `Person` object which may be *nullable* you may want to write the method something like this:

```
void doSome(Optional<Person> person) {
    /* and here you want to retrieve some property phone out of person
       you may write something like this:
    */
    Optional<String> phone = person.map((p) -> p.getPhone());
    phone.ifPresent((ph) -> dial(ph));
}

class Person {
    private String phone;
    // setters, getters
}
```

Here you have returned a `String` type which is automatically wrapped in an `Optional` type.

If `Person` class looked like this (i.e. `phone` is also `Optional`):

```
class Person {
    private Optional<String> phone;
    // setters, getters
}
```

In this case invoking `map()` function will wrap the returned value in `Optional` and yield something like:

```
Optional<Optional<String>>
```

But you may want `Optional<String>` instead, so here comes `flatMap()`:

```
void doSome(Optional<Person> person) {
    Optional<String> phone = person.flatMap((p) -> p.getPhone());
    phone.ifPresent((ph) -> dial(ph));
}
```

---

#### P.S.

Never call `get()` method (if you need to) on an `Optional` without checking it with `isPresent()` unless you can't live without `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I think this example is likely to distract from the nature of your answer because your class `Person` is misusing `Optional`. It is against the intention of the API to use `Optional` on members like this - see http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8-dev/2013-September/003274.html

Comment: @8bitjunkie Thanks for pointing that out, it differs from Scala's Option..

Answer (score 8):

What helped me was a look at the source code of the two functions.

**Map** - wraps the result in an Optional.

```
public<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    if (!isPresent())
        return empty();
    else {
        return Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(value)); //<--- wraps in an optional
    }
}
```

**flatMap** - returns the 'raw' object

```
public<U> Optional<U> flatMap(Function<? super T, Optional<U>> mapper) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    if (!isPresent())
        return empty();
    else {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(mapper.apply(value)); //<---  returns 'raw' object
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `flatMap` "returns the 'raw' object"? `flatMap` also returns the mapped object "wrapped" in an `Optional`. The difference is that in the case of `flatMap`, the mapper function wraps the mapped object in the `Optional` while `map` itself wraps the object in `Optional`.

Comment: @DerekMahar deleted mine, no need to re-post it, because you've edited your comment right.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me get a nice picture of it!

Answer (score 5):

- `Optional.map()`:

Takes every element and if the value exists, it is passed to the function:

```
Optional<T> optionalValue = ...;
Optional<Boolean> added = optionalValue.map(results::add);
```

Now **added** has one of three values: `true` or `false` wrapped into an ***Optional*** , if `optionalValue` was present, or an ***empty Optional*** otherwise.

If you don't need to process the result you can simply use `ifPresent()`, it doesn't have return value:

```
optionalValue.ifPresent(results::add);
```

- `Optional.flatMap()`:

Works similar to the same method of streams. Flattens out the stream of streams. With the difference that if the value is presented it is applied to function. Otherwise, an empty optional is returned.

You can use it for composing optional value functions calls.

Suppose we have methods:

```
public static Optional<Double> inverse(Double x) {
    return x == 0 ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(1 / x);
}

public static Optional<Double> squareRoot(Double x) {
    return x < 0 ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(Math.sqrt(x));
}
```

Then you can compute the square root of the inverse, like:

```
Optional<Double> result = inverse(-4.0).flatMap(MyMath::squareRoot);
```

or, if you prefer:

```
Optional<Double> result = Optional.of(-4.0)
                     .flatMap(MyMath::inverse)
                     .flatMap(MyMath::squareRoot);
```

If either the `inverse()` or the `squareRoot()` returns `Optional.empty()`, the result is empty.

Comment: This does not compile. Both of your expressions return an Optional<Double> rather than the Double that you are assigning the result to.

Comment: @JL_SO you are right. Because inverse has `Optional<Double>` type as return type.

Answer (score 1):

They do the **same** thing.

The **only difference** is that, the `lambda` return's type is **wrapped** by `Optional` or not.

For normal usage, `map` is shorter than `flatMap`

Example:

```
package bj;

import java.util.Optional;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        out.println(Optional.of(10).map    (x ->             x * x));
        out.println(Optional.of(10).flatMap(x -> Optional.of(x * x)));
        out.println(Optional.of(10).map    (x -> Optional.of(x * x).get()));

        out.println(Optional.<Integer>empty().map    (x ->             x * x));
        out.println(Optional.<Integer>empty().flatMap(x -> Optional.of(x * x)));
        out.println(Optional.<Integer>empty().map    (x -> Optional.of(x * x).get()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Optional[100]
Optional[100]
Optional[100]
Optional.empty
Optional.empty
Optional.empty
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer below link to understand in detail (best explanation which I could find):

https://www.programmergirl.com/java-8-map-flatmap-difference/

Both map and flatMap - accept Function. The return type of map() is a single value whereas flatMap  is returning stream of values

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper)

<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)
```

Comment: In your method signatures both return types are streams? I thought that `flatMap` would simply unwrap nested optional? Can you explain more how this relates to streams?

Comment: These are the signatures of Stream::map and Stream::flatMap. While similar in what they do, they are not the same. This answer is mostly irrelevant.