# Whats the difference between Optional.flatMap() and Stream.flatMap()

Tags: java, methods, java-8, java-stream, option-type

What is the difference between Optional.flatMap() and Stream.flatMap().

Correct flatMap on Stream:

```
    List<ObjectDTO> collect = types.stream()
            .flatMap(a -> client.getSthById(new URI(a)).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Exception while using flatMap on Optional:

```
        List<ObjectDTO> collect2 = client.getSthByObj(obje.get(), null).getBrowse()
                .flatMap(uri -> client.getSthById(uri).stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Why can't I use it in the same way?

Comment: what are you asking? this is really unclear, and did you read the docs and numerous other posts here about one and the other?

Comment: They perform very similar operations, hence the same name. The main difference is that one requires an `Optional` and a method that returns an `Optional` while the other requires a `Stream` and a method that returns a `Stream`.

Comment: Could you elaborate your examples into [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That would help.

Comment: Also the stacktrace from the exception that you say that you get would be helpful.

Comment: It would be good that you clarify your question to indicate exactly what you are trying to do, and give self-sufficient code snippets that show your problem ([mcve]). Even if you already got your answer, that will be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s hard to be sure from your code snippets where we don’t know the types of the variables you use nor the return types of the methods. But I *think* that the source of your error is that you are trying to pass a lambda that returns a `Stream` to `Optional.flatMap()`.

Let’s look at `Stream` first. [`Stream.flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) takes a function that returns a `Stream`. This seems to be exactly what you are giving it in your first code snippet.

`Optional` on the other hand: [`Optional.flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) requires a function that returns an `Optional`. If `getBrowse()` returns an `Optional`, then what you pass to `Optional.flatMap` is `uri -> physicalInventoryClient.getSublocationsByIds(uri).stream()`. This looks like your lambda returns a stream, not an `Optional`. When I try the same in my Eclipse, I get a compile error like the following:

> The method flatMap(Function<? super String,? extends Optional<?
>   extends U>>) in the type Optional<String> is not applicable for the
>   arguments ((Object x) -> {})

The solution? From Java 9 `Optional` has [a `stream` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--) that will probably let you achieve what you are trying. Again, without knowing your code it’s hard to suggest, but probably something like:

```
    List<SublocationBrowseDTO> collect2 = physicalInventoryClient.getSublocationsByLocation(masterLocation.get(), null)
            .getBrowse()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(uri -> physicalInventoryClient.getSublocationsByIds(uri).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Edit:** Alternative without stream:

```
    List<SublocationBrowseDTO> collect2 = physicalInventoryClient.getSublocationsByLocation(masterLocation.get(), null)
            .getBrowse()
            .map(uri -> physicalInventoryClient.getSublocationsByIds(uri))
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

The latter version requires that `getSublocationsById()` returns a list, but can probably be modified to work if the return type is something else. IMHO it’s a bit simpler.

Comment: Excuse me, that was my first question in stackoverflow. This answer fulfills my expectations. Thank you so much!

Comment: We’re all learning. And yes, it takes a bit to learn how to use this site. Welcome! BTW I thought of a different solution and added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`Optional` and `Stream` are two different beasts intended for separated purposes.

[`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) is a ***wrapper*** that holds a result that can be or not be "present" (`null`) and provided methods to deal which these two  conditions (present, or Not Present).

The `flatMap()` operation is an operation applied to the value held in your `Optional` wrapper. That operation must return an `Optional` as a result:

```
Optional<String> s = Optional.of("test input");
s.flatMap( input -> Optional.of(input));
```

Stream's [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) helps you to get and process nested elements of list elements.

---

#### Additional reading

- [What is the difference between Optional.flatMap and Optional.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864583/java-8-difference-between-optional-flatmap-and-optional-map)
- [What's the difference between map() and flatMap() methods in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/whats-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-methods-in-java-8/49297863#49297863)

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc: 
Optional.flatMap:

```
flatMap(Function<? super T,Optional<U>> mapper)
```

If a value is present, apply the provided Optional-bearing mapping function to it, return that result, otherwise return an empty Optional.

Stream.flatMap:

```
flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)
```

Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.

So the main difference is, that one returns a Stream, the other an Optional