# flatMap() to convert a stream of LinkedList<String> into a stream of String

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

My goal is exactly what the title say. What I'm doing is:

```
.stream().flatMap(x -> x.getTitles())
```

`getTitles()` returns a `LinkedList<String>`, and I expected `flatMap()` to do the job and create a stream of Strings instead of a stream of `LinkedList<String>`, but Eclipse says:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `LinkedList<String>` to `Stream<? extends Object>`

How can I do that? (I need to do it with streams, it's all part of a bigger stream computation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`flatMap` expects mapping to stream, not to collection. Use

```
.stream().flatMap(x -> x.getTitles().stream())
//                                   ^^^^^^^^ add this
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked, thanks!! However, why do I have to do that? Aren't `map()` and `flatMap()` supposed to  substitute the elements in the original stream with the ones obtained with the lambda expression? I thought that in the way that you wrote I would have created a stream of streams of (a single) string (which I don't think it's possible).

Comment: `map` is used when you want to have `Stream<A>` and map *each* element from that stream to *one* other element `B` so you would get `Stream<B>`. But `flatMap` is used when you want to map element `A` to possibly more than one elements, which comes from another stream. So if you have relation `a->stream{i,i}, b->stream{k,l}` stream of `a,b` can become stream of `{i,j,k,l}`.

Comment: Or lets take this example. Lets assume that you have steam of `List<Integer>`. If you do `map(list -> list.stream()` you will end up with `Stream<Stream<integer>>`, but with `flatMap` you are ending up with stream of elements from returned stream, so you are getting `Stream<Integer>`.

Comment: @RVKS You can find more info about map vs flatMap here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26684562/1393766

Comment: Another way you could do this: say `x` is an instance of `MyClass`, then you could do `.stream().map(MyClass::getTitles).flatMap(Collection::stream)`