# Why is this usage of Stream::flatMap wrong?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

I expected to be able to use Stream::flatMap like this

```
public static List<String> duplicate(String s) {

    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add(s);
    l.add(s);

    return l;
}


listOfStrings.stream().flatMap(str -> duplicate(str)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I get the following compiler error

> Test.java:25: error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s)
>   R     listOfStrings.stream().flatMap(str -> duplicate(str)).collect(Collectors.toList());
>
> (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
>         List cannot be converted to Stream)
>   where R,T are type-variables:
>       R extends Object declared in method flatMap(Function>)
>       T extends Object declared in interface Stream

In scala I can do what I believe to be equivalent

```
scala> List(1,2,3).flatMap(duplicate(_))
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

Why is this not a valid usage of flatMap in java?

Comment: check this answer among others on how and why to use flapMap() with java 8 Streams: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297863/755401

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The lambda expression in [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) needs to return a `Stream`, as can be seen by the argument of `flatMap` which is of type `Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>>`.

The following code will compile and run fine:

```
listOfStrings.stream()
             .flatMap(str -> duplicate(str).stream()) // note the .stream() here
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

because the lambda expression `str -> duplicate(str).stream()` is of type `Function<String, Stream<String>>`.

Comment: The return type for `<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)` is the same. Why doesn't map require `.stream()` but flatmap does?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to duplicate each object in the stream several times, you don't need to waste memory on this with additional `ArrayList`. There are several shorter and faster alternatives.

- Generate new stream using `Stream.generate`, then limit it:

  ```
  listOfStrings.stream()
               .flatMap(str -> Stream.generate(() -> str).limit(2))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- Generate sequence of numbers via `IntStream.range` and map them to the same string:

  ```
  listOfStrings.stream()
               .flatMap(str -> IntStream.range(0, 2).mapToObj(i -> str))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- Use good old `Collections.nCopies`:

  ```
  listOfStrings.stream()
               .flatMap(str -> Collections.nCopies(2, str).stream())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```

If you are sure that you will always duplicate exactly two times, there's the shortest alternative:

```
listOfStrings.stream()
             .flatMap(str -> Stream.of(str, str))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```