# Passing objects through streams and flatmaps

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I'm dealing with Java 8 streams and I wondering if I could resolve this problem in a fancy way.

That's my scenario:
Suppose I have a list of parties and inside each element I have the names of the members. I want to iterate over the list and make a new one with the names and which party they belong to.

My first approach was:

```
@Test
public void test(){

    Party firstParties = new Party("firstParty",Lists.newArrayList("Member 1","Member 2","Member 3"));
    Party secondParty = new Party("secondParty",Lists.newArrayList("Member 4","Member 5","Member 6"));

    List<Party> listOfParties = Lists.newArrayList();
    listOfParties.add(firstParty);
    listOfParties.add(secondParty);

    List<Elector> electors = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfParties.stream().forEach(party ->
        party.getMembers().forEach(memberName ->
            electors.add(new Elector(memberName,party.name))
        )
    );

}

class Party {
    List<String> members = Lists.newArrayList();
    String name = "";

    public Party(String name, List<String> members) {
        this.members = members;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }
}

class Elector{

    public Elector(String electorName,String partyName) {

    }

}
```

In my second approach I tried to use maps an flatmap's operations:

```
@Test
public void test(){

    Party firstParty = new Party("firstParty",Lists.newArrayList("Member 1","Member 2","Member 3"));
    Party secondParty = new Party("secondParty",Lists.newArrayList("Member 4","Member 5","Member 6"));

    List<Party> listOfParties = Lists.newArrayList();
    listOfParties.add(firstParty);
    listOfParties.add(secondParty);

    List<Elector> people = listOfParties.stream().map(party -> party.getMembers())
            .flatMap(members -> members.stream())
            .map(membersName -> new Elector(membersName, party.name)) #Here is my problem variable map doesn't exist
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

The problem is I can't access to the party object inside the map operation. 
So the question again is Can I do in a more functional way? (like the second approach)

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the hack is to flatmap into a stream of tuple, which would contain the member and its party. Something like `.flatMap(party -> party.getMembers().stream().map(member -> new Tuple<>(party, member))`. And since there is no built-in tuple class, you can make your own or (ab)use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`...

Comment: Or `Pair.of(party, member)` from commons-lang if you already have that dependency.

Comment: @Tunaki: you are thinking too complicated…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You decomposed too much into individual operations:

```
List<Elector> people = listOfParties.stream()
    .flatMap(party -> party.getMembers().stream()
        .map(membersName -> new Elector(membersName, party.name)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This works by moving both `map` steps into the `flatMap` step, where only the second one survives, now being applied to the returned “substream”. As pointed out in the comments of your question, you need some kind of `Pair` type to map the “substream” elements to, but your `Elector` type fulfills exactly that, as it is constructed using the two values you are interested in. So there is no need to map to a generic `Pair(member,party)` just to map to `Elector` afterwards.

Comment: Reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/26684710/191246 clarified what's going on here.

Answer (score 3):

To keep everything readable I would add a helper method in the `Party` class (or a static method somewhere else) to get a `Stream<Elector>`:

```
public Stream<Elector> electors() {
    return getMembers().stream().map(member -> new Elector(member, name));
}
// Alternatively
public static Stream<Elector> electors(final Party p) {
    return p.getMembers().stream().map(member -> new Elector(member, p.name));
}
```

And then just use that in your flatmap

```
final List<Elector> people = listOfParties.stream()
    .flatMap(Party::electors)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```