# Java 8: Flattening Stream<Stream>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want do a Cartesian product on Quarter on a year between the years specified

Year(2105, 2016) should return Quarter(2015, Q1), Quarter(2015, Q2)... Quarter(2016, Q4)

The enum representing Quarter would be

```
public enum Quarters {
    Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4
}
```

and the code I'm trying to come up with is stuck as below

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(this.getYear(), to.getYear())
    .boxed()
    .map(i -> Arrays
        .stream(Quarters.values())
        .map(q -> new Quarter(i, q))
    );
```

The above code return `Stream<Stream<Quarter>>` which I would require to be flattened to `Stream<Quarter>` any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `flatMap` ?

Comment: Or maybe also [What's the difference between map and flatMap methods in Java 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/whats-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-methods-in-java-8?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatMap( i -> i)` will essentially concatenate the streams.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `flatMap` to flatten your `Stream<Stream<Quarter>>` to a `Stream<Quarter>` :

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(this.getYear(), to.getYear())
    .boxed()
    .map(i -> Arrays
        .stream(Quarters.values())
        .map(q -> new Quarter(i, q))
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
    );
```

The body of the `flatMap` would simply be an identity function.

Or, as Alexis suggested, you can directly use `flatMap` instead of `map` :

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(this.getYear(), to.getYear())
    .boxed()
    .flatMap(i -> Arrays
        .stream(Quarters.values())
        .map(q -> new Quarter(i, q))
    );
```

Comment: Just use `flatMap(...)` instead of `map(...).flatMap(identity())`

Comment: @AlexisC. Good point, Thanks!

Comment: Compilation errors when I tried with the first snippet, flatMap works fine, haven't unit tested, but compiles just fine, so hope will work too.

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar My mistake. The first snippet should use `Function.identity ()`, not a method reference. Anyway, the second snippet is better.

Comment: Actually, the combination of `map` and `flatMap` has a point, if you use it to avoid the boxing overhead, i.e. instead of `.boxed().flatMap(…)` you can use `.mapToObj(…).flatMap(identity())`. It’s a work-around for the absence of `flatMapToObj`…