# Stream<Set<Object>> instead of Stream<Object>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class Person having a set of Objects Contacts. I want to get a stream of Contacts from the stream of Persons.

```
public class Persons{
     private Set<Contact> contacts;
}

persons.stream().map(Person::getContacts);
```

gives me `Stream<Set<Contact>>` rather a `Stream<Contact>`

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated as I am quite new to Java 8 and Streams.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Once you get the `Stream<Contact>` you won't know which person each contact belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Stream<Contact> contacts = persons.stream().flatMap(p -> p.getContacts().stream());
```

or that:

```
Stream<Contact> contacts = persons.stream().map(Person::getContacts).flatMap(Set::stream);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/whats-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-methods-in-java-8) excellent thread so that you may understand the difference between `map` and `flatMap`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [`Stream#flatMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) instead of `Stream#map`. The JavaDoc shows an example of flattening a list of lines from a file to a list of words within each line.  You can adapt the same technique to your domain model of `Person` and `Contact`.