# How to use stream in Java 8 to collect a couple of fields into one list?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

For example I have class `Person` with *name* and *surname* fields.

I want to collect a `List` of `String` (names and surnames all together) from `List` of `Person`, but it seems that I can't use map twice per one list or can't use stream twice per list.

My code is:

```
persons.stream()
   .map(Person::getName)
   .collect(Collectors.toSet())
   .stream().map(Person::getSurname) 
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

but it keeps telling me that `Person::getSurname` non-static method can't be referenced from static context.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably `Person::getName` returns a `String`? Then collecting that yields a `Set<String>`. So, you can't call `Person::getSurname` on the elements of that.

Comment: What is the result supposed to be? Just a `List<String>` with all of them mixed together?

Comment: When you say "names and surnames all together", do you mean concatenated? Alternating?

Comment: Jorn Vernee, that's right!

Comment: khelwood, yea, just mix of names and surnames in one list.

Comment: You are probably looking for `persons.stream().flatMap(p -> Stream.of(p.getName(), p.getSurname()).collect(Collectors.toSet())`

Comment: Alexis C, thanks!!! totally what I was looking for!

Comment: @user2620644 take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/whats-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-methods-in-java-8

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To get both names and surnames in the same list, you could do this:

```
List<String> set = persons.stream()
  .flatMap(p -> Stream.of(p.getName(),p.getSurname()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That's it, thanks!!! It works, but could you please answer, what does flatMap mean? You can reuse stream over the same list or what?

Comment: @user2620644 `flatMap` is one of the two methods that define a "monadic type". Take `Optional<A>`, which has a normal `map` function using a `Function<A,B>` to transform the content of the `Optional`. But in some cases you have a function that results in the wrapper type itself, e.g. `Function<A,Optional<B>>`. Using `map`would result in a nested `Optional<Optional<B>>`, so you need a method instead which "peels of" or "flattens" one layer - and that's where you use `flatMap`. In our case, every element is converted to a `Stream` itself, and `flatMap` "glues" these `Stream`s together.

Answer (score 7):

When you're doing :

```
persons.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

The result is a `Set<String>` that contains only the `name` of the `persons`.
Then you're recreating a stream from this `Set` and not from your `List<Person> persons`.

That's why you can not use `Person::getSurname` to map this `Set`.

The solution from @Alexis C. :
`persons.stream().flatMap(p -> Stream.of(p.getName(), p.getSurname()).collect(Collectors.toSet())` must do the job.

Comment: I get it, but what does flatMap means? What does it do?

Comment: FlatMap reduce all the `Stream<String>` produced by `Stream.of(p.getName(), p.getSurname())` into 1 `Stream<String>` and then you collect inside a `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look something like that:

```
persons.stream()
.map(person -> person.getName() + " " + person.getSurname)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It will concatenate the strings into one, I dont want this, I want list to consist of separate string objects.

Comment: Oh,  I mistunderstood your question. Go ahead with Landeis Answer then.

Answer (score 0):

if person has first name and middle name optional then use below code

```
return Stream.of(Optional.ofNullable(person)
.map(Person::getFirstName)
.orElse(null),
Optional.ofNullable(person)
.map(Person::getMiddleName)
.orElse(null))
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.collect(Collectors.joining(SPACE));
```