# Collecting lists from an object list using Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8

I have a class like this

```
public class Example {
    private List<Integer> ids;

    public getIds() {
        return this.ids; 
    }
}
```

If I have a list of objects of this class like this

```
List<Example> examples;
```

How would I be able to map the id lists of all examples into one list?
I tried like this:

```
List<Integer> concat = examples.stream().map(Example::getIds).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but getting an error with `Collectors.toList()`

What would be the correct way to achive this with Java 8 stream api?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between map and flatMap methods in Java 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/whats-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-methods-in-java-8). And even it is not a perfect duplicate, the answers there are useful.

Comment: Your method `getIds` does not have a return type.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

```
List<Integer> concat = examples.stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getIds().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `flatMap` and `map`

Comment: @CraigR8806 Extensive explanations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/whats-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-methods-in-java-8)

Comment: What would happen if `e.getIds()` returns an empty list or null? How could a test for empty list or null be included into the statement?

Comment: @gabriel "empty list" well, there's nothing in the list, but it would work just the same. "null" a `NullPointerException` would be thrown. How would you want to handle null; and why would you want to (specially) handle an empty list?

Comment: Ok, yes for an empty list you're right, it won't be a big problem. Concerning `null`: I wondered, what the lambda expression should/could return if I checked there if the list was `null` and to avoid a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Well you could do something like `{ List<Integer> ids = e.getIds(); if (ids == null) ids = Collections.emptyList(); return ids.stream(); }`. But consider that the null might itself be a bug; so it might be better to fix it rather than work around it.

Comment: Sure, you're right. Will have to look into that as well. Still, thank you for your effort! +1

Comment: you can use something like this .filter(Objects::nonNull) .. so you would get only notNull.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution by using method reference expression instead of lambda expression:

```
List<Integer> concat = examples.stream()
                               .map(Example::getIds)
                               .flatMap(List::stream)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use `Stream` and `Map` to collect the object list:

```
List<Integer> integerList = productsList.stream().map(x -> x.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```