# Is flatMap guaranteed to be lazy?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

Consider the following code:

```
urls.stream()
    .flatMap(url -> fetchDataFromInternet(url).stream())
    .filter(...)
    .findFirst()
    .get();
```

Will `fetchDataFromInternet` be called for second url when the first one was enough?

I tried with a smaller example and it looks like working as expected. i.e processes data one by one but can this behavior be relied on? If not, does calling `.sequential()` before `.flatMap(...)` help?

```
    Stream.of("one", "two", "three")
            .flatMap(num -> {
                System.out.println("Processing " + num);
                // return FetchFromInternetForNum(num).data().stream();
                return Stream.of(num);
            })
            .peek(num -> System.out.println("Peek before filter: "+ num))
            .filter(num -> num.length() > 0)
            .peek(num -> System.out.println("Peek after filter: "+ num))
            .forEach(num -> {
                System.out.println("Done " + num);
            });
```

Output:

```
Processing one
Peek before filter: one
Peek after filter: one
Done one
Processing two
Peek before filter: two
Peek after filter: two
Done two
Processing three
Peek before filter: three
Peek after filter: three
Done three
```

**Update**: Using official Oracle JDK8 if that matters on implementation

**Answer**:
Based on the comments and the answers below, flatmap is partially lazy. i.e reads the first stream fully and only when required, it goes for next. Reading a stream is eager but reading multiple streams is lazy.

If this behavior is intended, the API should let the function return an `Iterable` instead of a stream.

In other words: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288915/is-flatmap-guaranteed-to-be-lazy#comment79550832_46288915)

Comment: The doc on [parallelism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) says "When you create a stream, it is always a serial stream unless otherwise specified.", so a call to `.sequential()` isn't necessary.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: @pedromss Documentation doesn't say it explicitly. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-
And looks like there are few cases where it may not be lazy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229373/why-filter-after-flatmap-is-not-completely-lazy-in-java-streams

Comment: @balki the SO post you linked states in the accepted answer that intermediate operations are always lazy. Also, from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html): "Streams are lazy; computation on the source data is only performed when the terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are consumed only as needed." Flatmap is an intermediate operation

Comment: Thanks! It was not very obvious for me. I will accept if you add an answer.

Comment: `fetchDataFromInternet` will not be called more than necessary, but the elements returned by a particular `fetchDataFromInternet` invocation might get processed without laziness.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Under the current implementation*, `flatmap` is eager; like any other stateful intermediate operation (like `sorted` and `distinct`). And it's very easy to prove :

```
 int result = Stream.of(1)
            .flatMap(x -> Stream.generate(() -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()))
            .findFirst()
            .get();

    System.out.println(result);
```

This never finishes as `flatMap` is computed eagerly. For your example:

```
urls.stream()
    .flatMap(url -> fetchDataFromInternet(url).stream())
    .filter(...)
    .findFirst()
    .get();
```

It means that for each `url`, the `flatMap` will block all others operation that come after it, even if you care about a single one. So let's suppose that from a single `url` your `fetchDataFromInternet(url)` generates `10_000` lines, well your `findFirst` will have to wait for *all* 10_000 to be computed, even if you care about only one.

**EDIT**

This is fixed in Java 10, where we get our laziness back: see [JDK-8075939](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075939)

**EDIT 2**

This is fixed in Java 8 too (8u222): [JDK-8225328](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8225328)

Comment: Looks like it has been [backported](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8225328) to Java 8 too.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov thank you for the info - you can edit the answer too if you want.

Answer (score 5):

It’s not clear why you set up an example that does not address the actual question, you’re interested in. If you want to know, whether the processing is lazy when applying a short-circuiting operation like `findFirst()`, well, then use an example using `findFirst()` instead of `forEach` that processes all elements anyway. Also, put the logging statement right into the function whose evaluation you want to track:

```
Stream.of("hello", "world")
      .flatMap(s -> {
          System.out.println("flatMap function evaluated for \""+s+'"');
          return s.chars().boxed();
      })
      .peek(c -> System.out.printf("processing element %c%n", c))
      .filter(c -> c>'h')
      .findFirst()
      .ifPresent(c -> System.out.printf("found an %c%n", c));
```

```
flatMap function evaluated for "hello"
processing element h
processing element e
processing element l
processing element l
processing element o
found an l
```

This demonstrates that the function passed to `flatMap` gets evaluated lazily as expected while the elements of the returned (sub-)stream are not evaluated as lazy as possible, as already discussed in [the Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29229373/2711488) you have linked yourself.

So, regarding your `fetchDataFromInternet` method that gets invoked from the function passed to `flatMap`, you will get the desired laziness. But not for the data it returns.

Answer (score 1):

Today I also stumbled up on this bug. Behavior is not so strait forward, cause simple case, like below, is working fine, but similar production code doesn't work.

```
 stream(spliterator).map(o -> o).flatMap(Stream::of)..flatMap(Stream::of).findAny()
```

For guys who cannot wait another couple years for migration to JDK-10 there is a alternative true lazy stream. It doesn't support parallel. It was dedicated for JavaScript translation, but it worked out for me, cause interface is the same.

StreamHelper is collection based, but it is easy to adapt Spliterator.

https://github.com/yaitskov/j4ts/blob/stream/src/main/java/javaemul/internal/stream/StreamHelper.java