# Stream with limit(1) evaluates every element of stream

Tags: java

In my code, I'm creating a `Stream` consisting of the lines of a file. I then use `limit(1)` on the stream to process only one of its elements. But actually, all of the elements get processed, as shown by the `println()` statements in the `identity()` method.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        preprocessDataset();
    }

    private static int processedFiles = 0;

    public static void preprocessDataset() {
        Stream<Path> nqPaths = getProcessablePaths();
        Stream<String> lines = nqPaths.flatMap(Main::toLines).limit(1);
        writeLines(lines);
    }

    private static Stream<Path> getProcessablePaths() {
        return Stream.of(new File("/Users/sz/train/nq-train-00.jsonl").toPath());
    }

    private static Stream<String> toLines(Path path) {
        try {

            FileReader reader = new FileReader(path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            return bufferedReader.lines().map(Main::identity);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return Stream.empty();

        }
    }

    private static String identity(String line) {
        System.out.println("processing line " + line);
        return line;
    }

    public static void writeLines(Stream<String> lines) {
        try {

            String filePath = "/Users/sz/test/data.json";
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));

            lines.forEach(line -> {
                try {
                    bufferedWriter.write(line);
                    bufferedWriter.newLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(String.format("wrote %d lines.", ++processedFiles));
            });

            bufferedWriter.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The output:

```
processing line
wrote 1 lines.
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
processing line
```

If I remove the `limit(1)` call, it works as expected, with one line being processed for each written line:

```
processing line
wrote 1 lines.
processing line
wrote 2 lines.
processing line
wrote 3 lines.
processing line
wrote 4 lines.
processing line
wrote 5 lines.
processing line
wrote 6 lines.
processing line
```

Why is this happening? Why is Java executing the `identity()` method for every line in the file even when I set `limit(1)`?

Comment: This might be related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288915/is-flatmap-guaranteed-to-be-lazy

Comment: Which version of Java do you use? (I could not reproduce it with Java 11, but could with Java 8.)

Comment: @GaborBakos I'm on java 8.

Comment: Indeed, switching to Java 10 solved the issue.