# add a loop chaining method in java

Tags: java, loops, method-chaining

I have a program that runs chaining methods

```
MyObject o = MyObject.getInstance().method1().method2().go();
```

Now, this instance returns multiple lines of data,

I can execute them in a loop but I would rather do this:

```
MyObject o = MyObject.getInstance().foreach().method1().method2().go();
```

*I.e used a `for each`*

is it possible in Java to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Java 8, assuming getInstance() returns a stream:

```
MyObject.getInstance().forEach(item-> item.method1().method2().go() );
```

See the streaming API documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/

Answer (score 0):

No, foreach does not return an iterator.

However, `map` and `flatMap` provide return values which can be iterated over. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26684710/553865