# Java8: Stream map two properties in the same stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class `Model` with the following signature:

```
class Model {
        private String stringA;
        private String stringB;

        public Model(String stringA, String stringB) {
            this.stringA = stringA;
            this.stringB = stringB;
        }

        public String getStringA() {
            return stringA;
        }

        public String getStringB() {
            return stringB;
        }
}
```

I would like to map a `List<Model>` to a `List<String>` containing both stringA and stringB in a single stream

```
List<String> strings = models.stream()
                .mapFirst(Model::getStringA)
                .thenMap(Model::getStringB)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or:

```
List<String> strings = models.stream()
                .map(Mapping.and(Model::getStringA,Model::getStringB))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course none of them compiles, but you get the idea.

Is it somehow possible?

**Edit:**

Example:

```
Model ab = new Model("A","B");
Model cd = new Model("C","D");
List<String> stringsFromModels = {"A","B","C","D"};
```

Comment: When you say "both StringA and StringB", do you mean a concatenation? Or should your `List<String>` contain the `StringA` for your `Model` at index `0`, then your `StringB` for your `Model` at index `0`, then [...] at index `1` and so on?

Comment: A Stream generally does not like having to increase in size, that is not how it normally behaves, you *can* achieve what you want by using `flatMap` but that will be ugly. Is there any reason you don't want to use traditional `for` loops?

Comment: @Mena I mean the second way, so `List<String> strings` should contain every string from Model, both stringA and stringB. I will provide an example.

Comment: @luk2302 that is the actual solution but I was wondering if I could solve it in a stream

Comment: Then the answer is "yes, but it will neither be pretty nor better performance-wise"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can have a list of all the values one after another like so:

```
List<String> resultSet =
               modelList.stream()
                        .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getStringA(), e.getStringB()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The function passed to `flatMap` will be applied to each element yielding a  `Stream<String>`. The use of `flatMap` is necessary here to collapse all the nested `Stream<Stream<String>>` to a `Stream<String>` and therefore enabling us to collect the elements into a `List<String>`.

Comment: @Sunflame You're welcome. I've also added some additional explanation if it helps clarify the answer :).

Comment: Thanks, now it is a lot more clear how to use `flatMap`, I thought it used to merge `Collection`s or `Iterable`s in a single stream. It really helped.

Answer (score 7):

`flatMap` is your friend here:

```
models
    .stream()
    .flatMap(model -> Stream.of(model.getStringA(),model.getStringB()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`flatMap` takes a type R and expects to give a Stream (from list,collections, Array) of new Type RR back. For each `1` model  you get `n` new elements (in this case `StringA` and `StringB`):

```
{model_1[String_A1,String_B1] , model_2[String_A2,String_B2] , model_3[String_A3,String_B3]}
```

All your `n` elements 

`{ [String_A1,String_B1], [String_A2,String_B2],[String_A3,String_B3]}`

are then *flattened* that are placed into a new Stream with structure

`{String_A1,String_B1,String_A2,String_B2,String_A3,String_B3}`

of Type String.  That's how you have a new Stream.

You can use `flatMap` e.g when you have many collections/streams of elements that need to be merged into only one. For more simple explanations, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297863/755401)