# Java 8: Mapping multiple properties of class in same stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Hello my question is very similar to [Java8: Stream map two properties in the same stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553829/java8-stream-map-two-properties-in-the-same-stream) but for some reason I cannot get my code to work.

So like that question, say I have a class `Model`

```
class Model {
    private List<Integer> listA;
    private List<Integer> listB;
    private List<Integer> listC;
    public List<Integer> getListA() {
        return listA;
    }

    public List<Integer> getListB() {
        return listB;
    }
    public List<Integer> getListC() {
        return listC;
    }
}
```

So I want to combine these lists from a `List<Model> myList` using a stream and my code looks like this:

```
myList.stream()
      .flatmap(i -> Stream.of(i.getListA(), i.getListB(), i.getListC()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
      .get(0)
```

But this approach ends up returning an empty list. I would appreaciate any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must concatenate the 3 lists with [`Stream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream)).  Once you've concatenated the streams (don't cross them!), flat map them to a `Stream<Integer>`, then collect to a `List`.

```
myList.stream()
      .flatMap(m -> Stream.concat(Stream.concat(m.getListA().stream(),
                                  m.getListB().stream()),
                    m.getListC().stream()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With

```
List<Model> models = List.of(
    new Model(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6), Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9)),
    new Model(Arrays.asList(11, 12, 13), Arrays.asList(14, 15, 16), Arrays.asList(17, 18, 19)),
    new Model(Arrays.asList(21, 22, 23), Arrays.asList(24, 25, 26), Arrays.asList(27, 28, 29))
);
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the help! Since I think Stream.concat only allows for 2 parameters, what I did was followed the example that they gave in the Stream.concat documentation for concatening multiple streams: Streams.of(e.getListA().stream(), .... ).flatMap(s->s).collect(...) and that fixed it

Answer (score 3):

Well, the difference with the linked question is that you have three levels: a sequence of `Model`s, each model having multiple attributes. Those attributes are `List`s, so they as well may contain multiple elements.

Now you can use `flatMap` *twice* instead of once.

```java
myList.stream()
    .flatMap(model -> Stream.of(model.getListA(), model.getListB(), model.getListC())
        .flatMap(List::stream))
    .toList();
```