# Nested ArrayList to single dimension

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have some code that looks like this.

```
class A {}
class B extends A {
    private String name; // assume there's a getter
}
class C extends A {
    private List<B> items = new ArrayList<>(); // assume a getter
}
```

In another class, I have an ArrayList (`ArrayList<A>`). I'm trying to map this list to get all the names.

```
List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
// a while later
list.stream()
    .map(a -> {
        if (a instanceof B) {
            return ((B) a).getName();
        } else {
            C c = (C) a;
            return c.getItems().stream()
                .map(o::getName);
        }
    })
    ...
```

The problem here is that I end up with something like this (JSON for visual purposes).

```
["name", "someName", ["other name", "you get the idea"], "another name"]
```

How can I map this list so I end up with the following as my result?

```
["name", "someName", "other name", "you get the idea", "another name"]
```

Comment: Use a `flatMap`.. It would be useful if you show how you collect the result after the *map* step (the *else* returns a Stream whereas the *if* part returns a String). Are you collecting it into a `List<Object>`?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/whats-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-methods-in-java-8 it will help you understand the use of flatMap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

```
list.stream()
    .flatMap(a -> {
        if (a instanceof B) {
            return Stream.of(((B) a).getName());
        } else {
            C c = (C) a;
            return c.getItems().stream().map(o::getName);
        }
    })
    ...
```

This will produce a `Stream<String>` of all the names, without nesting.