# How to do migration java 7 to java 8 - forEach and return a List<Object> or null if input is null?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

My java7 code:

```
List<Argument<?>> args = expression.match(text);
if (args == null) {
    return null;
} else {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Argument<?> arg : args) {
        list.add(arg.getValue());
    }
    return list;
}
```

I try with `stream` + `flatMap` + `map` + `collect`

```
List<Object> list = args.stream().flatMap(arg -> arg.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toSet());...??
```

Comment: The `args.stream()` will result in a NPE without that `if(args == null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `flatMap` :

```
return (args == null) ? null : args.stream()
        .map(arg -> arg.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); //modified
```

*Side note*: Do not assign/return `null` for a `List<T>`, use `Collections.emptyList()` instead.

Comment: I need return `null` because my code is a matcher and my callers need have `null` if no match else a list of match.

Comment: is it possible include test of null in the same instruction or I keep `if (args == null) {...`?

Answer (score 2):

1. [Change `flatMap` to `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/whats-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-methods-in-java-8).
2. Change `Collectors.toSet()` to `Collectors.toList()`.
3. I assume a check `args == null` is done prior to `args.stream()`. Otherwise, you may get a NPE.

---

```
List<Argument<?>> args = expression.match(text);
return args == null ?
        null :
        args.stream().map(arg -> arg.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am not a supporter of returning `null`, though. You could return a `Collections.emptyList()` or an `Optional.empty()`.

Comment: I also prefer `Collections.emptyList()` or an `Optional.empty()` but I'm not the choice because users of my method wants to have null if there is no match (is it a matcher)

Comment: @sgrillon is there something wrong with my answer so you've changed your mind (unupvoted and unaccepted)?

Comment: **Your answer is good, thank you for your contribution.** I preferred the answer of @Naman because he answered more quickly and especially he went to the essential.