# What is the top first use case you think of, when you see the 'flatMap' method in someone else's code?

Tags: java, functional-programming

Sorry for some kind of theoretical question, but I'd like to find a way of quick reading someone else's functional code, building chain of methods use templates.

For example:

#### Case 1.

When I see use of **.peek** method or **.wireTap** from Spring Integration, I primarily expect logging, triggering monitoring or just transitional running external action, for instance:

```
.peek(params ->
    log.info("creating cache configuration {} for key class \"{}\" and value class \"{}\"",
        params.getName(), params.getKeyClass(), params.getValueClass()))
```

or

```
.peek(p ->
    Try.run(() -> cacheService.cacheProfile(p))
       .onFailure(ex ->
           log.warn("Unable to cache profile: {}", ex.toString())))
```

or

```
.wireTap(sf -> sf.handle(msg -> {
    monitoring.profileRequestsReceived();
    log.trace("Client info request(s) received: {}", msg);
```

#### Case 2.

When I see use of **.map** method or **.transform** from Spring Integration, I understand that I'm up to get result of `someFunction(input)`, for instance:

```
.map(e -> GenerateTokenRs.builder().token(e.getKey()).phoneNum(e.getValue()).build())
```

or

```
.transform(Message.class, msg -> {
   ErrorResponse response = (ErrorResponse) msg.getPayload();
   MessageBuilder builder = some tranforming;
   return builder.build();
})
```

#### Current case.

But I don't have such a common view to **.flatMap** method.
Would you give me your opinion about this, please?

#### Add 1:

To Turamarth: I know the difference between .map and .flatMap methods. I actively use both .map, and .flatMap in my code.

But I ask community for theirs experience and coding templates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between map and flatMap methods in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/whats-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-methods-in-java-8)

Comment: Typically flat map is used when we have collection of collections like list of lists, for instance `[ [a], [b,c], [d,e] ]` and we don't want to iterate over those collections like `[a]` `[b,c]` `[d,e]` but rather over its elements like `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`. So when I see `flatMap` I expect something along `streamOfElements.flatMap(ElementType::geInnerElementsAstStream)`.

Comment: @Turamarth it's not duplicate, have a look at my addition 1

Answer (score 3):

It always helps to study the signature/javadoc of the streamish methods to understand them:

> The flatMap() operation has the effect of applying a one-to-many transformation to the elements of the stream, and then flattening the resulting elements into a new stream.

So, typical code I expect, or wrote myself:

```
return someMap.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)
```

The *values* of that map are sets, and I want to pull the entries of **all these sets** into a single stream for further processing here.

In other words: it is about "pulling out things", and getting them into a stream/collection for further processing.

Comment: GhostCat, thanks for your reply! Your answer is in the way I wished to find desicions

Comment: @Torino You are very welcome. My first impulse when I saw your question title was to look for a good close reason, but I think you put in quite a lot of good thought, and I like your code examples. Now lets see if other people will contribute more examples, or if you will have to accept this answer in the end ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've found one more use template for **.flatMap**.

Let's have a look at the following code:

```
String s = valuesFromDb
.map(v -> v.get(k))
.getOrElse("0");
```

where `Option<Map<String, String>> valuesFromDb = Option.of(.....)`.

If there's an entry `k=null` in the map, then we'll get `null` as a result of code above.

But we'd like to have "0" in this case as well.

So let's add `.flatMap`:

```
String s = valuesFromDb
.map(v -> v.get(k))
.flatMap(Option::of)
.getOrElse("0");
```

Regardless of having `null` as map's value we will get "0".