# Is there a way to use Stream() inside of Stream()?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the below object, I would like to use Stream() in order to get the first input param where the name is equal to "target"
is it possible? or I can only stream the inputParam?

````
    "flow": [
        {
            "step": [
                {
                    "inputParam": [
                        {
                            "name": "inputname",
                            "value": "value"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}```
````

Comment: have you tried? If the element a Stream iterates over is a Collection of sorts, why wouldn't you be able to use a Stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flatMap` in streams.

[more about map and flat map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26684562/8283737)

```
 Optional<InputParam> optionalInputParam = flowCollection.stream()
                .flatMap(flow -> flow.getSteps().stream())
                .flatMap(step -> step.getInputParams().stream())
                .filter(inputParam -> inputParam.getName().equals("target"))
                .findFirst();
```

This is assuming you have `steps` in `Flow` object and `inputParams` in `Step` object and have defined getters on these attributes.

Comment: Thanks! this is the solution. Stream is new to me so im still learning.