# JAVA8 Optional and Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type, flatmap

Suppose I have this `class` model hierarchy:

```
public class A {
 private Integer id;
 private List<B> b;
}
```

And:

```
public class B {
 private Integer id;
 private List<C> c;
}
```

And finally:

```
public class C {
 private Integer id;
}
```

And a simple `Service`:

```
@Service
public class doSome {
  
  public void test() {
    Optional<A> a = Optional.of(a) // Suppose a is an instance with full hierarchy contains values
    /** *1 **/               // what I want to do
  }
}
```

Now what I want to do at the `*1` position is to use lambda to extract the `Optional` value (if exixsts) and map the subrelation to obtain all `id` of the `C` class. I have tried something like this:

```
  public void test() {
    Optional<A> a = Optional.of(a);
    List<Integer> temp = a.get().getB()
                                .stream()
                                .map(x -> x.getC())
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .map(y -> y.getId())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());   // works
  }
```

Now I would like to put inside my lambda the `a.get().getB()`, I have tried several ways but with no luck.

Anyway I don't understand why I can't use two consecutive `map` like

```
 .map(x -> x.getC())
 .flatMap(List::stream)
 .map(y -> y.getId())
```

without using `flatMap(List::stream)` in the middle... the `map` doesn't return a new `Stream` of Type R (class C in this case)? Why I have to `Stream` it again? where am I wrong?

----------------------- UPDATE ------------------

This is just an example, It's pretty clear that the `Optional` here is useless but in real case could comes by a `findById()` JPA Query.

Holger for this reasons I would put all inside a part of code, doing something like:

```
public <T> T findSome(Integer id) {
  Optional<T> opt = repository.findById(id);
  return opt.map(opt -> opt).orElse(null);
}
```

I have read here some solution like follows:

```
Optional.ofNullable(MyObject.getPeople())
  .map(people -> people                                                                    
    .stream()                                                                    
    .filter(person -> person.getName().equals("test1"))
    .findFirst()
    .map(person -> person.getId()))
  .orElse(null);
```

And I would like to adapt at my case but without no luck.

Comment: 1) it’s not clear why you create this superfluous `Optional` at all, then 2) it’s not clear what “I would like to put inside my lambda the `a.get().getB()`” is supposed to mean. Which lambda? And why do you want to put that expression inside it when you already have code that works fine? 3) See [What's the difference between map() and flatMap() methods in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26684562/2711488) or in short, can you invoke `getId()` on a `List<C>`? Or do you need a construct to tell that you want to do it for every element (e.g. by streaming over it)?

Comment: When you invoke a method that returns an optional on purpose, i.e. because it might return an empty optional you should not perform an unconditional invocation of `get` on it.

Comment: You have to use flatMap because you have a List of Lists (every B has a List of C and you have many Bs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) and newer, you can call `Optional#stream`:

```
List<Integer> temp = a.map(A::getB)
        .stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(B::getC)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(C::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you are stuck with [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you need to map to `Stream` (or return the empty one) and continue chaining:

```
List<Integer> temp = a.map(A::getB)
        .map(Collection::stream)
        .orElse(Stream.empty())
        .map(B::getC)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(C::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Note:** `Optional<A> a = Optional.of(a)` is not valid as `a` is already defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot, is what I was looking for, and `Optional<A> a  Optional.of(a)` is a typing error (or pseudocode at most!). Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. :) Please, next time try to avoid mixing such pseudocode with a real code as it might lead others to focus on that typo rather than posting an useful answer.