# Nested collections lambda iteration

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Suppose I have an object containing a collection,  each elements on the said collection contains a collection, and each collection contains a collection.

And I want to iterate on the deepest objects and apply the same code to it.

The imperative way is trivial, but is there a way to lambda-fy this all?

Here is how the code looks today:

```
My object o;
SecretType computedThingy = 78;
for (FirstLevelOfCollection coll : o.getList()) {
  for (SecondLevelOfCollection colColl : coll.getSet()) {
    for (MyCoolTinyObjects mcto : colColl.getFoo()) {
      mcto.setSecretValue(computedThingy);
    }
  }
}
```

I can see how to make a lambda out of the deepest loop:

```
colColl.getFoo().stream().forEach(x -> x.setSecretValue(computedThingy)
```

But can I do more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to the rescue, simple example with a nested collection of String

See also: 
[Java 8 Streams FlatMap method example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382453/java-8-streams-flatmap-method-example?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Turn a List of Lists into a List Using Lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147094/turn-a-list-of-lists-into-a-list-using-lambdas)

```
    Set<List<List<String>>> outerMostSet = new HashSet<>();
    List<List<String>> middleList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> innerMostList = new ArrayList<>();
    innerMostList.add("foo");
    innerMostList.add("bar");
    middleList.add(innerMostList);

    List<String> anotherInnerMostList = new ArrayList<>();
    anotherInnerMostList.add("another foo");

    middleList.add(anotherInnerMostList);
    outerMostSet.add(middleList);

    outerMostSet.stream()
                .flatMap(mid -> mid.stream())
                .flatMap(inner -> inner.stream())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Produces

```
foo 
bar 
another foo
```

Answer (score 5):

[flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) is available for such a purpose. What you get here is iteration over all elements of the various deepest collections as if they were a single collection:

```
o.getList().stream()
    .flatMap(c1 -> c1.getSet().stream())
    .flatMap(c2 -> c2.getFoo().stream())
    .forEach(x -> x.setSecretValue(computedThingy));
```