# How to iterate through nested java collections using lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I read through several threads about operating on the nested java collections using Lambda but none addressed my specific situation, although [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981669/nested-collections-lambda-iteration) came close and then took off to a different direction (flatMap). Please show me how to write the following code in Lambda.

```
 for(AppUser user : users){
     List<CustomerOrder> orders = user.getOrders();
     for(CustomerOrder order : orders){
             order.setConsumer(user);
             List<LineItem> items = order.getLineItems();
             for (LineItem item : items){
                  item.setOrder(order);
             }
     }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Your loop is modifying the elements it loops through. I'd say it's not really a good candidate for streams. IMHO it's ok as it is.

Comment: Thanks guys, I worked it out myself.

Comment: @TonyHimself if you found a solution you could help future readers by answering your own question.

Comment: First I need to test it then I will publish the final solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is iterate, the `forEach` method on either the Stream.java or the Iterable.java should be enough. Here is the "streamy" way of doing what you are trying to do with the for loops

```
users.stream().forEach( user ->
        user.getOrders().stream().forEach( order -> {
            order.setConsumer(user);
            order.getLineItems().stream().forEach(
                    lineItem -> lineItem.setOrder(order)
            );
        }
));
```

Although you don't really need to convert the iterable returned by by those getters to streams.

Comment: Smarth, since you took the time to work on the solution, I will check yours as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I came up with but I see that Smarth Ktyal already posted an answer.

```
users
                    .stream()
                    .forEach(e->e.getOrders()
                            .stream()
                            .forEach(k->{
                                k.setConsumer(e);
                                k.getLineItems()
                                    .stream()
                                    .forEach(l->l.setOrder(k));
                                }
                            )
                    );
```