# How to convert multiple attributes of object into List<String> using java 8

Tags: java, string, list, java-8, java-stream

I am wondering if there is a way to combine multiple attributes from an object into a list of String. In My Case, I have an object with the name "debitCardVO" and I want it to convert from object to List

Here is my code Snippet:

```
for (DebitCardVO debitCardVO : debitCardVOList) {
    List<String> debitCardList   = debitCardVOList.stream()
            .map(DebitCardVO::getCardBranchCode,DebitCardVO::getAccountNo)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: What's the use case for that? Assuming all those attributes can be converted to strings what would you do with that? If it's for serialization why not use Json or some other string representation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`flatMap` can help you [flatMap vs map](https://www.baeldung.com/java-difference-map-and-flatmap)

```
List<String> debitCardList = debitCardVOList.stream()
                    .flatMap(d -> Stream.of(d.getCardBranchCode(),d.getAccountNo()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Other examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382453/java-8-streams-flatmap-method-example)

Comment: Indeed the first thing that came to my mind as well. +1