# I have a list that contains strings. How do I use .split() on each one (with forEach)?

Tags: java, string, list, foreach, split

I cant use loops like for/while. forEach is okay.

I have a list like this:

```
List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<String>(); 
listStrings.add("12 14 15"); 
listStrings.add("15 13 17"); 
listStrings.add("14 15 13");
```

How do I split each String with .split() in this list at the " " without using 
for/while loops?

How the new List newList is supposed to look like:

```
List<String> newList {"12", "14, "15", "15", ...}
```

("Why cant you use loops like for/while"-> its for a task and I have to practise using streams.)

Thank´s in advance.

Comment: If we do it for you, we will practice, but you won't. Why not read the documentation, and try something? That's how one practices.

Comment: I already did. All I found was about one splitting one string and saving his split parts in an array. That doesnt help me.

Comment: @okaycoolG , use `flatmap` to flatten each elements in list and then split the list on the basis of `" "`

Comment: If you know how to loop through strings, and you also know how to split one string, then you can split multiple strings: you loop through the strings, and for each one, you split it. You should at least try doing that.

Comment: @JBNizet like the other answer shows, its not necessary to use a loop.

Comment: Of course it's not the ideal solution. But you **asked** for a solution using forEach. Read your question. And it's easier to start with simpler things first when practicing.

Comment: If you read my question carefully it says forEach is "okay". Im learning functional java programming so using no loop at all and just collecting in a new list is perfect.

Comment: And its title says "How do I use .split() on each one (with forEach)?". I know how to use streams. I know very well about flatMap. Whether you should or not use forEach doesn't matter. What you should do though, is read the javadoc, try things before asking, and show your efforts in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any loop to create a list, just collect the stream

```
Stream.of("12 14 15", "15 13 17", "14 15 13")  // Stream<String>
  .map(s -> s.split(" "))  // Stream<String[]>
  .flatMap(Stream::of) // Stream<String>
  .collect(Collectors.toList());  // List<String>
```

If you must start with a list, then replace first line with `listStrings.stream()`

[See example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28402445/2308683)

Otherwise, you just `add` within a forEach

```
Stream.of("12 14 15", "15 13 17", "14 15 13").
  .map(s -> s.split(" "))  // Stream<String[]>
  .flatMap(Stream::of) // Stream<String>
  .forEach(s -> newList.add(s));
```

Comment: @okaycoolG , yes use `" "`

Comment: I would rather like to see some explanation than just posting a answer. It does not help a newbie.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. I do understand everything but the Arrays.stream part. When Im streaming a List, why do I have to use Arrays.stream?

Comment: @okay What does `String.split` return?

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh okay an array with the split Strings. Of course. Thank you for your quick answer and explanation.