# How to split the integers in the array list?

Tags: java

first of all sorry for bad english.
Is it possible to split the numbers into half in my array list ?
I added each  number using .add

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();
    num.add(24);
    num.add(18);
    num.add(12);
    num.add(8);
    num.add(20);
    System.out.println(num);
  
    
}
```

Output: [24,18,12,8,20]

I want to split it into half
like this:
[12,12,9,9,6,6,4,4,10,10]

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What if number is odd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping it simple:

```
List<Integer> numSplit = new ArrayList<>():
for (Integer n : num) {
    numSplit.add(n / 2);
    numSplit.add(n / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a Java [Stream](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams) with the [flatMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382453/java-8-streams-flatmap-method-example) method:

```java
List<Integer> num = Arrays.asList(24, 18, 12, 8, 20);
List<Integer> splitted = num.stream()
    .flatMap(n -> Stream.of(n/2, n/2))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Gotta love streams +1, though I might prefer a simple loop actually in this case.

Comment: Even with streams, `Stream.of(n/2, n/2)` would be much simpler.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? What can I do better about the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplest approach without any consideration about odd numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();
    num.add(24);
    num.add(18);
    num.add(12);
    num.add(8);
    num.add(20);
    System.out.println(doJob(num));     
}   

private static List<Integer> doJob(List<Integer> lst){
    List<Integer> retval = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Integer a : lst){
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            retval.add(a/2);
        }
    }
  return retval;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another fancy stream-based way of splitting with multiplication and division replaced with shifts `<<` and `>>`:

```java
List<Integer> half2 =IntStream.range(0, num.size() << 1) // create indexes from 0 to 2*n - 1
                              .map(i -> num.get(i>>1)>>1) // get the same element of array for "new" pair of indexes and divide it by 2
                              .boxed()
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```