# How to use flat map for flating HashMap keys value into one set when there is a list of Map in Java stream

Tags: java, stream, flatmap

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list =new ArrayList();
Map<String, Object> map1 =new HashMap();
List<String> values =new ArrayList();
values.add("TEST")
values.add("TEST1")
map1.put("level",values);
Map<String, Object> map2 =new HashMap();
List<String> values2 =new ArrayList();
values2.add("TEST2")
values2.add("TEST3")
map2.put("level",values2);
list.add(map1);
list.add(map2);
```

I want the result like a list of flat string values

```
List<String> values =["TEST","TEST1","TES2","TEST3"]
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are **no** streams in your code, which by the way would fail to compile. Please share your attempt and specify the issue you've encountered? Every question of SO is expected to demonstrate an **effort**. Please get familiar with the guide-lines on how to ask questions [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `list.stream().flatMap(map -> map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)).toList()`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382453/java-8-streams-flatmap-method-example

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Object> collect = list
                .stream()
                .flatMap(x -> x.entrySet().stream())
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .flatMap(x -> {
                            if (x instanceof Collection<?>) {
                                return ((Collection<?>) x).stream();
                            } else {
                                return Stream.of(x);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Maps to have typed values, eg

```
List<Map<String, List<String>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
```

Then use `flatMap()` twice to double flatten the collections:

```
List<String> allValues = list.stream() // a stream of Maps
  .map(Map::values) // a stream of Collection<List<String>>
  .flatMap(Collection::stream) // a stream of List<String>
  .flatMap(List::stream) // a stream of String
  .collect(toList());
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/Rt68Ia).

---

If you leave the values of the Maps as `Object`, you need the cast them:

```
List<String> allValues = list.stream() // a stream of Maps
  .map(Map::values) // a stream of Collection<Object>
  .map(o -> (Collection<List<String>>)o)
  .flatMap(Collection::stream) // a stream of List<Object>
  .map(o -> (List<String>)o)
  .flatMap(List::stream) // a stream of String
  .collect(toList());
```

Which is uglier, less safe and unnecessary with the correct typing.